# Css rotate in IE9 preview

Tags: internet-explorer, css, rotation, internet-explorer-9

Is it possible to rotate content by any angle in the new IE9 preview? Filter in IE8 could rotate by multiples of 90, was this changed / improved? Or is here any other way (besides drawing with canvas and svg) to rotate text and divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumedly it will support CSS transforms by the time it's final.

Comment: When you "Assume"... ;-)   I've learned that with expectations for the "next" IE release you are better off to vote for the bug if it is entered in Connect (if not, create it)... then cross your fingers.  If the item gets updated by the IE Team as "included" in an upcoming preview/beta - consider yourself lucky.  Beyond that, silence is usually a good sign that they're deferring to address the item in this release. :-(

Comment: Thanks, I take it like there's no way to do it now.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the question is still open for you. One can use [-ms-transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ff468705#_CSS3_2D_Transforms). I use it for example in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CheckboxesWithVerticalHeaders1.htm) (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974324/jqgrid-using-multiple-methods-to-filter-data/3979490#3979490)).