# jqGrid: using multiple methods to filter data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, search, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

My requirement is to show a page with multiple filters to apply to grid data.

Suppose we are talking about Orders and an order has the following attributes

```
public class Order {
    public int OrderID
    public DateTime OrderDate
    public DateTime ShipmentDate
    public int OrderTotal
    public int OrderStatus
}
```

Inside the jqgrid object I am showing all the attributes **except the OrderStatus**

The requirement is to create a view that has

- the jqGrid on the left part
- a panel on the right

Inside the right panel the user will see a list of checkboxes that represents every possible OrderStatus value and he want to search using both methods (for example selecting the checkbox "Shipped Orders" and then filtering the grid with Amount greater than a value)

I have already configured the advanced filtering (`multiplesearch:true`) inside the jqGrid object and I am able to create complex filters combining fields and logical operators.

Any ideas on how I can submit even the data from the right panel when the user press the search button?

**Update 1**:

Preamble: Oleg sample is fantastic but unfortunately does not fits requirements of my customer :(

@Oleg: I do not understand why you think that:

> If the data are outside of the grid
>   you will be show the order details on
>   the right pane only for selected row.
>   So the user will have not so good
>   overview of the data.

maybe my description was not so clear but I am not going to show any order detail. To better clarify my requirement I have modified your sample to show you the desired final UI which is as in the following image:
[image: UI as teh customer want it]

The customer want to filter the data in the grid using two methods or both together:

- Using the `multiplesearch` facilities provided by the grid itself (thanks for the workaround mention)
- Using the custom Search Panel (the one with the checkboxes on the right) provided

From a functional point of view the requirement is very easy to express: When the user click on a checkbox or make a search using the native `multiplesearch` I should post values to the server including also the checkboxes state.

To summarize I should:

- Add the checkboxes state when a post is made through the native `multiplesearch`
- Add the current `multiplesearch` state (if any) when the user click on a checkbox

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I understand this requirement very good. In the close case I used checkboxes **inside of** jqGrid. The most advantage to having the information inside of jqGrid is not only the possibility of easy searching. If the data are outside of the grid you will be show the order details on the right pane **only for selected row**. So the user will have not so good *overview* of the data.

To be able to place many checkboxes in the table without permanent horizontal scrolling I rotated headers of the columns having "checkbox with the technique described in [Vertical text inside table headers using a JavaScript-based SVG library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705174/vertical-textes-inside-of-table-headers-with-respect-of-a-javascript-based-on-svg). This rotation looks not perfect in IE, but in other browser it works perfect.

You can hold the data from the `OrderStatus` field in a hidden column and decode the bitmask to boolean which build checkboxes either on the client or on the server side.

Because use want to use `multiplesearch:true` I have to mention about a bug in [jQuery.clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) which follow to the bug in jqGrid multi-search in all versions of IE browsers. If you define more as one search filters only the first one will be used because the operation field of all other filters will be read as `undefined`. It's a pity, but  the bug is also not fixed in the jQuery 1.4.3 just published. To be able to use `multiplesearch:true` you can use workaround suggestion by [Jiho Han on trirand.com forum](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/in-multiple-search-second-and-subsequent-ops-are-sent-as-undefined-in-ie6/).

All together you can see in [the demo example](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CheckboxesWithVerticalHeaders.htm) which produce the grid

[image]

where you can search for multiple fields

[image]

The corresponding code:

```
var myData = [
    { orderID: "10", orderDate: "2010-09-18", shipmentDate: "2010-09-20", orderStatus: "2" },
    { orderID: "15", orderDate: "2010-09-20", shipmentDate: "2010-09-24", orderStatus: "3" },
    { orderID: "20", orderDate: "2010-10-16", shipmentDate: "2010-10-17", orderStatus: "1" }
];
// decode 'orderStatus' column and add additional boolean data based on the bitmap mask
for (var i=0, l=myData.length; i<l; i++) {
    var myRow = myData[i];
    var orderStatus = parseInt(myRow.orderStatus, 10);
    myRow.airPost = (orderStatus & 2) != 0? "1": "0";
    myRow.heavy = (orderStatus & 1) != 0? "1": "0";
}
var grid = jQuery('#list');
grid.jqGrid({
    data: myData,
    datatype: 'local',
    caption: 'Order Details',
    height: 'auto',
    gridview: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    pager: '#pager',
    rownumbers: true,
    colNames: ['Order ID', 'Order', 'Shipment', 'Air-Post', 'Heavy', 'RowVersion'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'orderID', index: 'orderID', key:true, width: 120, sorttype: 'int' },
        { name: 'orderDate', index: 'orderDate', width: 180,
          sorttype: 'date', formatter: 'date' },
        { name: 'shipmentDate', index: 'shipmentDate', width: 180,
          sorttype: 'date', formatter: 'date' },
        { name: 'airPost', width: 21, index: 'airPost', formatter: 'checkbox', align: 'center',
          editoptions: { value: "1:0" }, stype: 'select', searchoptions: { value: "1:Yes;0:No" } },
        { name: 'heavy', width: 21, index: 'heavy', formatter: 'checkbox', align: 'center',
          editoptions: { value: "1:0" }, stype: "select", searchoptions: { value: "1:Yes;0:No" } },
        { name: 'orderStatus', index: 'orderStatus', width: 50, hidden: true }
    ]
}).jqGrid ('navGrid', '#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, refresh: true, view: false },
            {},{},{},{multipleSearch:true})
  .jqGrid ('navButtonAdd', '#pager', { caption: "", buttonicon: "ui-icon-calculator", title: "choose columns",
      onClickButton: function() {
          grid.jqGrid('columnChooser');
      }
  });
```

where `rotateCheckboxColumnHeaders` and the bugfix in the advanced search defined so

```
// we use workaround from http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/in-multiple-search-second-and-subsequent-ops-are-sent-as-undefined-in-ie6/
// to fix the bug in the jQuery.clone (see http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6793 and
// dscussion on the http://api.jquery.com/clone/
jQuery.event.special.click = {
    setup: function() {
        if (jQuery(this).hasClass("ui-search")) {
            jQuery(this).bind("click", jQuery.event.special.click.handler);
        }
        return false;
    },
    teardown: function() {
        jQuery(this).unbind("click", jQuery.event.special.click.handler);
        return false;
    },
    handler: function(event) {
        jQuery(".ui-searchFilter td.ops select").attr("name", "op");
    }
};
var rotateCheckboxColumnHeaders = function (grid, headerHeight) {
    // we use grid as context (if one have more as one table on tnhe page)
    var trHead = jQuery("thead:first tr", grid.hdiv);
    var cm = grid.getGridParam("colModel");
    jQuery("thead:first tr th").height(headerHeight);
    headerHeight = jQuery("thead:first tr th").height();

    for (var iCol = 0; iCol < cm.length; iCol++) {
        var cmi = cm[iCol];
        if (cmi.formatter === 'checkbox') {
            // we must set width of column header div BEFOR adding class "rotate" to
            // prevent text cutting based on the current column width
            var headDiv = jQuery("th:eq(" + iCol + ") div", trHead);
            headDiv.width(headerHeight).addClass("rotate");
            if (!jQuery.browser.msie) {
                if (jQuery.browser.mozilla) {
                    headDiv.css("left", (cmi.width - headerHeight) / 2 + 3).css("bottom", 7);
                }
                else {
                    headDiv.css("left", (cmi.width - headerHeight) / 2);
                }
            }
            else {
                var ieVer = jQuery.browser.version.substr(0, 3);
                // Internet Explorer
                if (ieVer !== "6.0" && ieVer !== "7.0") {
                    jQuery("span", headDiv).css("left", 0);
                    headDiv.css("left", cmi.width / 2 - 4).css("bottom", headerHeight / 2);
                }
                else {
                    headDiv.css("left", 3);
                }
                headDiv.parent().css("zoom",1);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

If you do prefer to hold the checkboxes outside of the grid you can do the decoding of the bit-mask `OrderStatus` inside of [onSelectRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) event handler.

**UPDATED**: I really something misunderstood your requirements at the beginning. Look at the [modified example](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CheckboxesWithVerticalHeaders1.htm). Now it looks like
[image]

and it is more close to what you need.

Comment: wow!!! fantastic sample. Thanks for spending the time tu put things together. Anyway this does not fit my requirement and moreover I think that I did not explain it at the best. Please have a look to my post edit to have further details. Thanks!

Comment: @Lorenzo: I am not sure that you have seen the my **"UDPATED"** part which I've written after you undated your question. Is this more close to solving your problem?

Comment: Great! I had the time to see your update only today. This is exactly what I was looking for. Can't give a +5 but for sure: thank you! :)

Comment: @Lorenzo: I am glad to hear it. I think that the example could help other people also.

Comment: I have found another method of doing the same things in a quicker way. Can you please have a look at it in the other answer and give me some advice if there are any drawbacks on using it? Thanks!

Comment: @Oleg great example! this is awesome, I'm wondering if there's some "gotcha" with trying to do this exact [same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763879/jqgrid-postdata-property-not-loading-pre-loaded-filter) (programmatically set filter in jqgrid) with just ONE filter. so setting the searchField, searchOper, and searchString properties ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Just as a follow up I am including here another method that I have found to abtain the same result.

This method suppose to use the `postData` parameter of jqGrid. Inside the method I have defined various function that verify the checkboxes current status and sends a parameter to the server where it can be used for filtering.

This is a sample

```
postData: {
    pending: function () {
        if ($("#cb_pending").is(':checked')) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The advantage of this solution respect to the one depicted by Oleg is that it is possible to use mixed logical operators (AND/OR) on the server side whereas using the filters section as in the [Oleg answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974324/jqgrid-using-multiple-methods-to-filter-data/3979490#3979490) it is not possible.

Happy coding!

Comment: To suggest you the same was my first idea. I suggest many people to do this (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928371/how-to-filter-the-jqgrid-data-not-using-the-built-in-search-filter-box/2928819#2928819), but I quickly found some problems. 1) You don't wrote which datatype ('json', 'local', ...) you use 2) It was unknown whether you use `loadonce:frue` and so the client side searching. 3) The most important is that it can be **conflicts** between the filter from the multiple (advanced) searching and the checkboxes from the external filter. I should explain the problem in more details:

Comment: Because one from your requirement is the usage of `multiplesearch` facilities you have to hold the information about the boolean status (like "pending") **inside of jqGrid**. You can of cause modify the multisearch dialog inside of `afterShowSearch` (see for example suggestion of Justin Ethier from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981874/multiple-search-with-multiplefields-by-default. I find the way a little to complex, but it will work. The largest problem I see **conflicts** between the filter. Let us we have for example a hidden column "pending" and used advanced searching to set "fasle"

Comment: Then we check the external filter and check "Pending" which corresponds to "pending:true". Which value have to use? At least you have to reset multisearch filter like I described in the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989786/jqgrid-clear-search-criteria. After understanding of all the problems I decide to choose the way from my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981874/multiple-search-with-multiplefields-by-default/3981986#3981986. I synchronize external filters with internal filters and it helps to avoid conflicts.

Comment: If you use data on the server you can decode the `OrderStatus` to 1 and 0 on the server side instead of doing this on the client side in `loadCompleted` (I thought about this also and included a possible solution in the commented part from the code of http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CheckboxesWithVerticalHeaders.htm). The problem with the **conflicts** between external and internal filters you have to solve nevertheless.