# Multiple search with multiplefields by default

Tags: jquery, search, jqgrid

So, there is a jqGrid, with declaration, smth like:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
...
bunch of stuff
...
).searchGrid({ multipleSearch: true });
```

which is fine, when I click Search button, it brings me modal form with I guess first column and a dropdown of sopts: searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'cn']}.
Now, i want to be able to display a couple of such fields by default not just one. I know I can add those later, by clicking Add, but I want to display them by default.

Having toolbar search is not an option.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [Toolbar Searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching). It shows one field per searchable column. If you use additionally `stringResult:true` option, you will receive the most compatible results to the [Advanced Searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching). By the way it you include both features [Toolbar Searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching) and [Advanced Searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching) (`multipleSearch: true`) the advanced searching dialog will be initialized with the last searching results from the [Toolbar Searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching). So you will have two or three rows in the [Advanced Searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching)  at the beginning.

**UPDATED**: The reason why after the usage of the [Toolbar Searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching) the dialog with the [Advanced Searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching) will be displayed not empty is that both use `filters` parameters of the `postData`. So if you initialize the `postData` you can receive a good starting point. See on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/multisearchfilter.htm). You will see

[image]

**UPDATE**: In [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429100/when-restoring-jqgrid-via-jqgridimport-search-information-is-incorrect/5430447#5430447) you will find how to delete the last line of the searching dialog (with "Inv No") which are not the part of the searching rules from the `postData.filters`.

Comment: Cool man, actually, I've done that using solution Justin provided and it works fine, however, tried yours as well - easy. Very easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this using the jqGrid API. Instead, you will have to use the `afterShowSearch` event to call a function after the search dialog is displayed. In that function you could programmatically add new rows, setting each one to the desired values.

Comment: Thanks Justin, this is the way to go, I hoped I can avoid doing this.