# Filter jqGrid Data by Date Range?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am trying to filter the jqGrid data by date range - that is, by "dateFrom" and "DateTo". Once the date is selected, I have tried to implement:

```
var dateFilter = {
                groupOp: "AND",
                rules: [
                { "field": "date", "op": "ge", "data": dateFrom },
                { "field": "date", "op": "le", "data": dateTo }
            ]
            }

    jQuery('#' + gridId).jqGrid('setGridParam', {

        postData: {
            filters: JSON.stringify(dateFilter)
        }
    }).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

But this doesn't seem to work ? I am using ASP.NET MVC but had hoped to do this on the client side by simply filtering the data to between the selected dates ?

Can anyone assist ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correct [the old demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/multisearchfilter.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981874/multiple-search-with-multiplefields-by-default/3981986#3981986) and [another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MultisearchFilterAtStart.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973361/how-can-i-preserve-the-search-filters-in-jqgrid-on-page-reload/4977896#4977896) will gives you code fragments which you need. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272850/is-there-an-api-in-jqgrid-to-add-advanced-filters-to-post-data/5273385#5273385) you could find additionally examples how to construct the `filters` dynamically.

Comment: Hi Oleg! :) Thanks for the response. How can I do this without the "searchbox" appearing. i.e. I just want to filter the data once the user has selected the date range and the data changes ? The first answer seems to show the searchbox [which I don't want too] ?

Comment: @Tom: If you set `postData.filters` and then call `.trigger('reloadGrid')` the grid will be refreshed. Is what you mean? Which `datatype` has your grid? Do you use `loadonce:true` parameter?

Comment: @Oleg - so I updated my code above. Using JSON, loadonce:true is used yes and now using the above code ? Is this correct or ?

Comment: @Tom: In general it's correct, but you need to set `search:true` parameter. I recommend that you additionally reset always the page number with `.trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:1}]);`

Comment: @Oleg thanks for the help :) Lastly, how do you customise the dateFormat ? i.e. of the Date field - is there a setting to make it appear like dd/mm/yyyy etc ?

Comment: found it - http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options - thanks :)

Comment: @Oleg - yep accepted. Searching the data and just trying to ensure that the format is the same ? Do I just use datefmt:'mm-dd-yyyy' within the colModel ?

Comment: @Tom: The situation could be a little more complexer. So you should describe your situation more exactly. Which date format has your **source** data? What features you use? Do you use `datepicker` for example?

Comment: @Tom: To understand more what I mean look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Localization1.htm) and [this one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalFormEditingWithContextmenu.htm)