# jqGrid has issues loading subgrid in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I've been trying to get the "[Grid as Subgrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html#t14)" feature working and have not been having much luck.  I thought it was something wrong I was doing in my code, as it was working fine in a stand-alone test.  However, I finally noticed the *only* difference between my app and my test page was my app was running on IE7 and I was running my test page in Firefox.  Sure enough, when I loaded the test page in IE7 I had the same issue.

The code that will repro the issue on IE7 is as follows:

```
$(function () {
    function loadTasks(subgrid_id, row_id)
    {
        var id = subgrid_id + '_t';
        $('#' + subgrid_id).html('<table id="' + id + '"></table>');
        jQuery("#" + id).jqGrid({
            datatype: 'local',
            colNames: ['No','Item','Qty','Unit'],
            colModel: [
                {name:'num',index:'num',width:80,key:true},
                {name:'item',index:'item',width:130},
                {name:'qty',index:'qty',width:70,align:'right'},
                {name:'unit',index:'unit',width:70,align:'right'}
            ],
            height: '100%'
        });
    }

    var x = $("#grid").jqGrid({
        jsonReader: { root: "rows", repeatitems: false },
        datatype: "json",
        height: 'auto',
        autowidth: true,
        forceFit: true,
        colNames:['ID','Name'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'id', key:true, index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int", jsonmap:"id"},
            {name:'name', index:'foobar', width:90,  jsonmap: "name"}
        ],

        subGrid: true,
        subGridRowExpanded: loadTasks,
        caption: "Results"
    });

    var jsonData = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Apple'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Banana'},
        {id: 3, name: 'Pear'},
        {id: 4, name: 'Orange'}
    ];

    x[0].addJSONData( { rows: jsonData } );
});
```

It seems to create some bogus elements on each row, which don't render correctly inside the row.  Here's a screen capture of how this renders on IE7:

[image: IE7 Screen Shot]

What's odd is those "undefined" rows are actually part of the valid grid rows, if I hover the mouse over "Apple", then the first *undefined* row also highlights.

The main reason I chose jqGrid over the other grids was its support for nesting multiple grids (which we really need for our app), however our corporate standard is still IE7 so we need to support this browser.  Is there anything I can do to make this feature work right under IE7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reported the bug [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/small-typing-bug-in-the-usage-of-addsubgridcell-in-addjsondata/#p26374). The problem was the typing error in [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.2/js/grid.base.js#L1360) where `+=` was used instead of `=`. As the result `undefined` was added to every row having subgrid.

It's untypical, but Tony modified the code of jqGrid after my bug report and **published it on [the download page](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) under the same version number 4.3.2**. So there are two *different* versions of jqGrid (with the bug and without it) with the same version number.

So to solve the problem you should just refresh the jqGrid 4.3.2 which you use.

**UPDATED**: I downloaded the sources of "new jqGrid 4.3.2" and I am very surprised because it contains not only the current bug fix, but also many other changes which was done in jqGrid last time. Many from the changes was suggested by my by the way. For example one can use now custom controls in the Searching Dialog (see my recent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10284605/315935)), one can use `searchOnEnter` and `closeOnEscape` in the SearchingDialog, new `afterChange` callback is there. Locales for English and German are [fixed](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/304). For example now it will be used comma as `thousandsSeparator` in `grid.locale-en.js`. It's very strange, but new versions of `grid.locale-en.js` and `grid.locale-de.js` are placed only in `src\i18n` subdirectory. The subdirectory `js\i18n` contains **old** version of the files (???). I can continue...

**In any way I recommend everyone to refresh the sources of jqGrid 4.3.2 previously downloaded from [the download page](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6).**

Comment: Oh, awesome!  Looks like this was literally fixed days ago..  I was thinking I was gonna have to dig down into this code myself.  Thanks for all your recent jqGrid help, @Oleg..

Comment: @MikeChristensen: You are welcome! I am very surprised, but the "new jqGrid 4.3.2" version contains many new features (see "UPDATED" part of my answer).

Comment: Yea, sounds like someone forgot to inc the build number..  That'll create some confusion in bug reports!

Comment: @MikeChristensen: Exactly! It's what I mean.