# Loading Search template filter from the database in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to store and load the search template using the database. While doing that, I am unable to change the value of the tmplLabel, tmplNames,tmplFilters.
I am calling loadTemplates() function that goes to the server to get the data and store in 3 variables. This function is being called at loadComplete(). 
Please let me know how can I reset the value of the templates.
I am talking about something like http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Answer (score 0):

Searching Templates is an interesting feature which are not frequently used. To use it one should use `tmplNames` and `tmplFilters` (optionally `tmplLabel`) which are [parameters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching#options) of the searching module. If's important that you use `recreateFilter: true` option additionally. So you can set the options of

```js
var mySearchOptions = {
        // it's just some options which you use
        multipleSearch: true,
        multipleGroup: true,
        recreateFilter: true,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterSearch: true,
        overlay: 0
    },
    $grid = $("#grid");

$grid.jqGrid({
    // ... your jqGrid options
    loadComplete: function (data) {
        // you should modify the next line correspond to the place of
        // tmplNames and tmplFilters in the server response
        if (data.tmplNames && data.tmplFilters) {
            mySearchOptions.tmplNames = data.tmplNames;
            mySearchOptions.tmplFilters = data.tmplFilters;
        }
    }
});
$grid.jqGrid('navGrid', {/*navGrid option*/}, {/*Edit options*/}, {/*Add options*/},
    {/*Del options*/},
    mySearchOptions);
```

I suppose that you have already correct code, but you don't use `recreateFilter: true` option. So previous opened Searching Dialog will be shown instead of to recreate the dialog with current options.

P.S. I recommend you additionally refresh the sources of jqGrid 4.3.2 (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10302130/315935)). You will have better keyboard support, can use `searchOnEnter` and `closeOnEscape` options, `afterChange` callback and custom controls in the searching dialog (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10284605/315935)).