# jqGrid - format ratio field as percent value

Tags: jqgrid, percentage, formatter

My server code transfers some column as a ratio value, 0.0 to 1.0. I need to format **and** edit it as a percent. I would like to do it on JavaScript side, without modifying server-side. So if I add a custom formatter to just multiply the value by 100,  display works as expected. Moreover, when I hit edit button, inline edit box also displays value as percentage. The trouble starts when I save - the value gets converted with formatter **one more time**, giving me things like 10000. So OK, I need symmetry here, so I create an unformatter which just divides value by 100. But that doesn't work too - now edit control displays it as a ratio which not what I wanted (although saving now works correctly).

Is there any way around without changing the server code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the *unformatter* in favour of *custom* edit type, just use this in your `colModel`:

```
{ ..., edittype: 'custom', editoptions: { custom_element: function(value, options) { return $('<input type="text" value="' + value + '"/>'); }, custom_value: function(element){ return parseFloat(element.val())/100; }  }}
```

Answer (score 6):

To have full support of your custom type of data like 0.0 to 1.0 displayed as percent value inclusive editing and searching you have to implements:

1. implement `formatter` to display the data in the grid in the custom way.
2. implement `unformat` to allow access to the data from its "visual representation". The method will be used by jqGrid in some situations (for example during initializing phase of form editing).
3. define `sorttype`, which could be some compatible type of data like `'number'` or your custom sorting function.
4. use `edittype: 'custom'` and implement `custom_element` and `custom_value` of `editoptions` (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#custom)).
5. use `stype: 'custom'` and implement `custom_element` and `custom_value` of `editoptions`.

In some situations one from the steps could be skipped, but in the common case you have to think about implementation all of the steps. You should verify which steps from above are still not implemented in your solution.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ranking1_441.htm) is the modification of the demo from [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4842450/315935) and [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10284605/315935). The demo is *not oriented on your direct question*. It shows just *why* and *how* one can full implement custom control in jqGrid. The functionally of form editing works not full in the demo only because of no server part implemented. If needed one could use the approach from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12296186/315935) which shows how local form editing can be implemented in jqGrid. I don't wanted to make the code more complex as requiret to show the main purpose of the demo.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer.