# jqGrid custom element radio button column not returning selected value after edit on saveRow

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqGrid which gets json data from a service. I have to add radio buttons to a column when in edit mode. This has to be inline edit. I need to update records in batch.
I have created a custom element and custom value to show radio buttons on `selectRow` in jqGrid.
The issue I have is that I can't get the value of the selected radio button.Instead it always returns the value of first radio button.
Code can be found [link](http://jsfiddle.net/srinivaspotluri/xx7Jg/10/)

Following is code that creates custom element

```js
function radioelem(value, options) {
    var receivedradio = '<input type="radio" name="receivednaradio" value="R"';
    var breakline = '/>Received<br>';
    var naradio = '<input type="radio" name="receivednaradio" value="N"';
    var endnaradio = '/>NA<br>';
    if (value == 'Received') {
        var radiohtml = receivedradio + ' checked="checked"' + breakline + naradio + endnaradio;
        return radiohtml;
    }
    else if (value == 'NA') {
        var radiohtml = receivedradio + breakline + naradio + ' checked="checked"' + endnaradio;
        return radiohtml;
    }
    else {
        return receivedradio + breakline + naradio + endnaradio;
    }
};

function radiovalue(elem, operation, value) {
    if (operation === 'get') {
        return $(elem).val();
    } else if (operation === 'set') {
        if ($(elem).is(':checked') === false) {
            $(elem).filter('[value=' + value + ']').attr('checked', true);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: @Oleg has answered the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691828/jqgrid-custom-edittype-radio-button-column-custom-element-not-firing-set-event). Working demo is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xx7Jg/8/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem in you code is that your implementation of `custom_element` (the function `radioelem`) returns HTML fragment which is **not one element**. `radioelem` returns

```html
<input type="radio" ... value="R"/><input type="radio" ... value="R"/>
```

as string. It consists from **two** input elements. So custom control failed in the case. You will be able to understand the problem if you examine the code how jqGrid use it. Look at [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/grid.common.js#L461-L467) of jqGrid code which I rewrite in simplified form as following

```js
var celm = options.custom_element.call($t,vl,options);
if(celm) {
    celm = $(celm).addClass("customelement").attr({id:options.id,name:options.name});
    $(elem).empty().append(celm);
}
```

jqGrid uses `$(celm)` where `celm` is the string returned from the `custom_element` function. In your case `$(celm)` will be jQuery wrapper of **two** `<input>` elements. I mean that `$(celm) === 2`. So instead of setting class "customelement" on **one** custom element the code `$(celm).addClass("customelement")` will add class "customelement" to **both** `<input>` elements. The next call (call of `attr`) set *the same* `id` on **both** `<input>` elements. How you know ids maust be unique, but the code do produces `id` duplicates.

To be exactly your implementation of `custom_element` (the function `radioelem`) returns even more complex HTML fragment

```html
<input type="radio" ... value="R"/><br/><input type="radio" ... value="R"/><br/>
```

If you examine the code which produce jqGrid at the end from the HTML fragment you will see very funny and very wrong HTML fragment like below

```html
<input name="NA" class="customelement" id="2_NA" type="radio" value="R">
Received
<br class="customelement" id="2_NA" name="NA">
<input name="NA" class="customelement" id="2_NA" type="radio" value="N">
NA
<br class="customelement" id="2_NA" name="NA">
```

Probably you didn't seen ever before so strange `<br/>` elements. You can see that the code fragment contains 4 elements with the same `id="2_NA"`. After that you should be not wonder that the custom control works not as expected.

**To fix the problem you need just place the code which you returned before inside of `<span>...</span>` or inside of `<div>...</div>`**:

```js
function radioelem(value, options) {
    var receivedradio = '<input type="radio" name="receivednaradio" value="R"',
        breakline = '/>Received<br>',
        naradio = '<input type="radio" name="receivednaradio" value="N"',
        endnaradio = '/>NA<br>';

    if (value === 'Received') {
        return "<span>" + receivedradio + ' checked="checked"' + breakline + naradio + endnaradio + "</span>";
    }
    if (value === 'NA') {
        return "<span>" + receivedradio + breakline + naradio + ' checked="checked"' + endnaradio + "</span>";
    }
    return "<span>" + receivedradio + breakline + naradio + endnaradio + "</span>";
}
```