# jqGrid - Custom forms layout (edit, add, del)

Tags: layout, jqgrid

I'm trying to customize the form layout of edit/add/del dialogs but the problem is that the height of my custom fields are not following the standard height (from the fields created automatically by jqgrid). Here is an image:
[image]

What I want is that the height of td.DataTD from my custom fields 'Responsável' and 'Componente' keep the same as the other fields. Here is the important part of my code:

```
beforeShowForm: function(form) {
     $('#tr_responsavel').html('<td class="CaptionTD">Responsável</td><td class="DataTD">&nbsp;<table><td><select role="select" id="resp" name="responsavel" size="1" class="FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"><option role="option" value="1">Usuário</option><option role="option" value="2">Área</option><option role="option" value="3">Grupo</option></select></td><td><input id="inputResponsavel" type="text" role="textbox" class="FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td><td><a href="#" onclick="teste()"> <img src="img/search.png" width="25" height="25"></a></td></table></td>');
     $('#tr_componente').html('<td class="CaptionTD">Componente</td><td class="DataTD">&nbsp;<table><td><input id="comp" type="text" role="textbox"></td><td><a href="#" onclick="teste2()"> <img src="img/search.png" width="25" height="25"></a></td></table></td>');    
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you *replace* existing jqGrid fields with another HTML code? Additionally it seems strange to set `<table>` inside of the field 'Responsável'. How you imagine that jqGrid *get* the results from such custom fields? Is it not more easy to *append* or *prepend* standard input fields of the Add/Edit form with additional information. In the case the standard fields with the standard ids will stay *unchanged* and you will have less problems. jqGrid will get the information from the fields without any problems. If one uses jQuery UI Autocomplete or jQuery UI Datepicker controls it do that.

If you *really need* custom field you should follow [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#custom) and use `edittype: "custom"`. Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ranking1_441.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12744780/315935) for more information.

Comment: Actually, I'm replacing because I was having a similar problem when using appendTo(): td.DataTD width was making all the content messy (there was too much blank space aside the fields). I'm using <table> to fix the problem I've just exposed. I'm gonna try using edittype then.. Thanks Oleg, The Almighty jqGrid Master :)

Comment: @lucasdc: You are welcome! You can post the code which uses `appendTo` or/and `prependTo`. You can additionally reduce the `width` of the standard fields to have more exact total width. In any way there are many ways to solve your problem. If you would have more problems you can post the corresponding code or better URL to the demo which reproduce the problem. You can use http://jsfiddle.net/ for example to prepare the live demo.