# jQuery jqGrid edittrules issue - silent value change on maxvalue check instead of error popup

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, popup, behavior, silent

Firefox 37.0.1 on Windows 7 Pro. jqGrid  4.4.1, cell editing mode. Two editable cells act differently on submit  and I can't figure out why. `column1` element has `maxValue` passed as `{{maximum_discount_value}}`, and when I go over the limit it gives a pop-up with the error description mentioning max allowed value correctly. `column2` element mas `maxValue` pointing to a function returning `maxValue`, and when I go over the limit it silently changes the value in the table to allowed `maxValue` about a second after I hit enter instead of giving me the same pop-up as I expect. What makes `column2` to behave differently and how to make it to give me a pop-up?
Thanks.

```
$("#{{ grid_id }}").jqGrid({
        '{% trans "JQGRID_COLUMN1" %}',
        '{% trans "JQGRID_COLUMN2" %}',
    colModel:[
        {name : "column1", index : "some_index1",
            width : 25,
            sortable : false,
            classes : "editable",
            editable : true,
            edittype : "custom",
            editrules : {
                number : true,
                minValue : 0,
                maxValue : {{ maximum_discount_value }}
            },
            editoptions : {
                maxlength : 5,
                size : 5,
                custom_element: function_for_element,
                custom_value: function_for_value
            }
        {name : "column2", index : "some_index2",
            width : 25,
            sortable : false,
            classes : "editable",
            editable : true,
            edittype : "custom",
            editrules : {
                number : true,
                minValue : 0,
                maxValue : function_for_maximum_discount_value
            },
            editoptions : {
                maxlength : 5,
                size : 5,
                custom_element: function_for_element,
                custom_value: function_for_value
            }
            ]

function function_for_maximum_discount_value(elem) {
    maximum_discount_value=  $(elem).attr("maximum_discount_value");
    return maximum_discount_value;
}
```

Comment: which editing mode you use? which version of jqGrid you use? You use `edittype:'custom'` which required specifying `custom_element` and `custom_value` callbacks in `editoptions` (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#custom)). Could you include *full definition of the columns in `colModel`*? `editrules` used to validate the value and to display an error message. No changing of values will be done. The value of `maxValue` must be the number. No callback function is allowed.

Comment: @Oleg - thanks for the quick response, added the details

Comment: You are welcome! The code which you included contains some `function_for_element` and `function_for_value` without the implementation.  I'm not sure that you really need `edittype : "custom"`. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ranking1_441.htm) from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12744780/315935). One need to `edittype : "custom"` in case of really custom editing control. To be able to help you I need to know answers on the following questions: **which editing mode you use? which version of jqGrid you use?**

Comment: @Oleg.  jqGrid 4.4.1, cell editing mode. Yes, I skipped some parts that are irrelevant here. What I am trying to do is to set different maxValue for different rows on edit inside `$("#{{ grid_id }}").jqGrid` (which defines a row structure). I thought I can do it with a callback function. Let's say in the demo it's not editable pilot's name  but an editable numeric field, and in the first row I don't allow to enter a number > 50 but in the second row it should prevent entering a number > 70, both with a standard error popup. I have a data["list_maxvalues"] list which I am passing from Django.

Comment: @Oleg Now I have to attach those maxvalue limits to different rows in the table.  And apparently `$("#{{ grid_id }}").jqGrid` object is not the right place to define this "maxvalue -by-row" limit.

Answer (score 0):

The code which you use for `column2` have absolutely wrong value for `editrules`. It seems that you mix [the custom editing control](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#custom) with the validation rules.

The option under `editrules` will be used *after* the editing filed are read at the end of editing. If you use `editrules: { number : true }` then you can include additional properties `minValue` and `maxValue` inside of `editrules`. The values of `minValue` and `maxValue` must be numbers. To callback functions are allowed. Even if you would use [custom validation rule](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#custom_checking_example) then you can define `editrules: {custom: true, custom_func: function mypricecheck (value, colname) {...}}`, but even in the case the `value` is the string read from the input filed. No access to original input field (like `$(elem).attr("maximum_discount_value")` in your code) is possible here.

You can implement some other scenarios, but the code will depend on [the editing mode](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs#editing) which you use (inline editing, cell editing or form editing).

Comment: Thanks a lot,  I assumed that I could use callback functions for the keys in `editrules` just like I do in `editoptions`, turned out I was  wrong. At least for the `maxValue` and `minValue` keys. Sorry can't upvote, need to collect some reputation first..