# jqgrid having column with splitcell.Every Splitcell will have 2 values.How to make 1st value is editable & 2nd is non-editable?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Using custom formatter, we can split the cell of a specific column in jqGrid.
This cell will have two values. But i need one value is editable and another is non-ediatble.

One example for splitting cell is as follow "jsfiddle.net/fbfcn/5yqRn/2/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jqGrid custom formatter allows to display custom data in the grid. You can use `edittype: "custom"` and `stype: "custom"` to implement custom editing of custom searching too. See [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3055626/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12744780/315935) for more details.

Comment: But ,I have scenario where i have used hidden columns to show in splitcells. And i need to edit the existing 1st value. and save into database. Follow this example : "jsfiddle.net/fbfcn/5yqRn/2/". I need to edit only orderNo not location on cellEdit

Comment: @kulfi: The demo which you posted is really bad. Moreover you don't need (you don't really use) any hidden columns. See http://jsfiddle.net/5yqRn/193/. By the way your demo don't contain any editing. It makes more difficult to understand what you need to implement.

Comment: @kulfi: I can't write all the code for you. In general you need mostly to define [unformatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter#unformatting) always if you define the formatter. I recommend you to use the latest version of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) too instead of usage old jqGrid 4.6. You can load free jqGrid from CDN (see [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)). Then you should use *some editing mode*. For example in case of cell editing: http://jsfiddle.net/5yqRn/196/