# Calling the page with jqGrid with enabled search?

Tags: jqgrid

I try to call one page with jqGrid (`windows.location.href='localhost/jqgrid?_search=true`') enabling search setting the parameter `_search` true, but it doesn't work as jqGrid append the search parameter by itself. `http://catalog.localhost/de/jqgrid/index/c_edition?_search=true&rows=10&page=1&searchField=work_id&searchOper=eq&searchString=3&_search=false&nd=1296026941396&rows=20&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc` How can we solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The usage of `windows.location.href` to set url having `?_search=true` seems me the wrong way. jqGrid can get per AJAX request data from the server. So you should set `url` parameter of the jqGrid on the new page and not set `windows.location.href` to the url.

Moreover the usage of `_search=true` parameter to start searching is also the wrong way. See links from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566242/how-can-i-set-postdata-search-to-true-in-the-request-in-jqgrid/4566654#4566654) for more information.

Comment: You mean that setting of the search parameters is possible only by using of grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { search: true, postData: newPostData }); and not by passing GET-parameters? The idea of using windows.location.href is to link one page with jqgrid to another one with jqgrid with complete page load passing some parameters, and not DOM-load.

Comment: @Anatoliy: What I mean is that you have to provide **two** different server urls: *one* which produce pure JSON or XML data to fill the grid contain (this url should support `_search` and other jqGrid parameters) and *another* which use set per `windows.location.href`. The last url get HTML/XHTML and JavaScript which define jqGrid. To tell the truth I personally prefer to use Master/Detail scenario where setting of `windows.location.href` is not needed and the second (detail) grid will be displayed on the same page below the master grid.

Comment: You are right, it is exactly scenario I have. But: as you might see above (in my question), the jqGrid appends `_search` parameters by itself and my setting is overwritten. Can I disable this automatic appending? Ad. `windows.location.href` vs Master/Detail - at the moment I prefer clear distinction as it seems to be easier for user to capture data from only one grid. Furthermore, what is with smaller displays with res 1024x867?

Comment: @Anatoliy: My main problem to understand you is following: it you set `windows.location.href` to an URL it means the url to HTML page. The `url` parameter of jqGrid response with JSON or XML data. So I don't understand why you use `?_search=true` for the HTML page? So I don't understand how you organize your server code. Nevertheless if you want that jqGrid **not append _search parameter** to the url you can use additional parameter `prmNames: { search: null }` of jqGrid.

Comment: Yes, with href I set the url to HTML page. Imagine, i have a grid works and artists. From each grid I will make a link to works of the given artist, or from works to the artist. I dont want to use subgrid, as I have deep relations, and it would be like grid->subgrid->subsubgrid and so on. I use the parameter ?_search to pass it through to ajax controller, and thus limiting the output of data. Is the concept below now much clearer?