# jqGrid '_search' parameter not being set in URL

Tags: jquery-plugins, jqgrid, url-parameters

I have the following code:

```
$("#perform_search").click(function() {    
  var postdata = $("#translationsList").jqGrid('getGridParam','postData');
  postdata._search = true;
  postdata.searchString = $("#auto_complete_search").val();
  console.log('postdata._search: ' + postdata._search);
  jQuery("#translationsList").trigger("reloadGrid", [{page:1}]);
});
```

When I click on the button with ID `perform_search` the resulting URL is below, and the value `searchString=hello` is pulled from a text field with an id of `auto_complete_search`:

`[domainname]/translations_feed.php?language_cd=EN`**&_search=false**`&nd=1308754288459&rows=20&page=1&sidx=phrase&sord=asc&searchString=hello`

... and what's supposed to happen is that the URL string has `_search=true`, but as you can see from the sample URL, the value being passed is `_search=false` **NOTE**: line 5, where I output the value of `postdata._search` to the console, the console shows `postdata._search: true` as expected, so that appears to be working as expected.

Seems like all other params are passing through just fine.

**UPDATE**

Seems that, if I first use the built-in search button (the little magnifying glass icon in jqGrid), that is sets the "_search=true" param correctly - and after that my button works fine. Not sure what the connection between to the two is, but essentially it seems as if my param is still being ignored either way. For example, if I do a search via the magnifying glass, and change my javascript so that LINE 5 reads `postdata._search = false` it passes `_search=true` (in other words, LINE 5 seems to be ignored completely).

Wondering if I'm simply setting the wrong variable on `postdata`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered an already [closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566242/how-can-i-set-postdata-search-to-true-in-the-request-in-jqgrid/4566654#4566654) like yours. The problem is that you should be setting the `search` parameter on the jqGrid itself, and not trying to alter the postData in this way.

In other words, to set `_search` as `true` you should set `search` parameter of jqGrid to `true` and not set any properties of `postData` directly. Similarly, you should not set `page` parameter of `postData`. Instead use the `rowNum` parameter.

So,  your code should be much simpler:

```
$("#perform_search").click(function() {    
  $("#translationsList").jqGrid('setGridParam', { search: true, postData: { searchString:$("#auto_complete_search").val() } });
  jQuery("#translationsList").trigger("reloadGrid", [{page:1}]);
});
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. The combination of this answer, and referring to your answer on the other question took care of it for me. I've added an edit to your answer that includes the final code, and some clarification.

Comment: I'd post the edit myself, but I don't have edit rights quite yet.