# How do I rebuild a JQGrid query on page refresh?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using JQGrid to implement some requirements on a client site and love the tool, but have been unable to overcome one obstacle.

I need to keep the search parameters in place on a page refresh.  I am using Multiple search and have the first part down which is to grab the search parameters when a search is performed.  I am using the following code to do it:

```
...
loadBeforeSend: function (xhr) {
  var postData = $("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData');
  var outData = '';
  $.each(postData, function(key, value) {
    if (key!='_search'){
      outData = outData + key + '=' + value + '|';
    }
  });
  window.location.hash = escape(outData);
},
...
```

This works great and on refresh I can easily grab the search data, however I have been unable to figure out how to default the search parameters to these values.

I am willing to move over to a filter toolbar implementation if that is easier.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is just modification of some `postData` properties. Some other old answers about very close subjects could show you how to manipulate `postData` properties: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981874/multiple-search-with-multiplefields-by-default/3981986#3981986), [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989786/jqgrid-clear-search-criteria/3992417#3992417), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974324/jqgrid-using-multiple-methods-to-filter-data/3979490#3979490) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492963/jqgrid-client-side-searching/4509018#4509018). All the example from the answers shows which role play `postData` and `search` parameter for all kind of jqGrid searching.