# How can I preserve the search filters in jqGrid on page reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I found many discussions that were close to what I need, and this question is the 
closest - [How can I set postData._search to true in the request in jqGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566242).

As I'm struggling with almost the same problem, and just can't get it working - I want to setup "search" and "filters" during the initial loading of the jqGrid - say, on the page reload, and I have my filters stored in the session - and I tried everything I found in Oleg's examples - it just doesn't work!

That's what I'm trying to do -

```
loadBeforeSend: function (xhr) {
    var grid = jQuery('#' + block_id);
    var postData = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','postData');
    jQuery.extend(postData,{filters:MyFilters});
    grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', {search: true, postData: postData});
    console.log(grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','postData'));
}
```

The console printout shows that the filters are in place, but the _search is still false, and the actual Post gets sent even with no filters:

```
_search   false
block_id  report_block_1table
nd        1297451574526
page      1
rows      25
sidx      id
sord      desc
```

However, if I put exactly the same code -  with the addition of

```
grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
```

line - into some button's onClickButton function, and later click the button - everything works; but I need to make it work on "page reload"!

Any ideas? It's driving me crazy...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to me that you are not the first person who ask the same question. Recently I asked on [the close question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949837/i-need-sme-help-automating-jqgrid-filters-please/4950386#4950386) (read many comments to the answer). Another [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981874/multiple-search-with-multiplefields-by-default/3981986#3981986) including [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MultisearchFilterAtStart.htm) could probably answer on some your opened questions.

Your code using `beforeRequest` don't work just because the function `beforeRequest` will be caled immediately before the ajax call and the changing of the `search` parameter is **too late**. Moreover overwiting of `filters` everytime is probably not the best idea. In the case the user will not able to set any other grid filter.

So I can repeat, that the imlementation of the solution which you need is very simple. You should just set `filters` property of the `postData` parameter of jqGrid to the filter which you need and set another jqGrid parameter `search:true` additionally. It's all! Later the user will be able to open advance searching dialog and overwrite the filters. The user can also click on "Reset" button of the advance searching dialog and set `filters` to empty string and `search:false`.

For better understanding I have to clear how `search` parameter or some other jqGrid will be used in the URL. There are parameter [prmNames](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) of jqGrid which defines **the names of parameters** send as a part of URL or as a part of data POSTed to the server. The default value of [prmNames](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) contain `search:"_search"` and the code of internal [populate](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.base.js#L1539) function used by jqGrid has the following simplified code fragment:

```
var prm = {}, pN=ts.p.prmNames;
if(pN.search !== null) {prm[pN.search] = ts.p.search;}
if(pN.nd !== null) {prm[pN.nd] = new Date().getTime();}
if(pN.rows !== null) {prm[pN.rows]= ts.p.rowNum;}
if(pN.page !== null) {prm[pN.page]= ts.p.page;}
if(pN.sort !== null) {prm[pN.sort]= ts.p.sortname;}
if(pN.order !== null) {prm[pN.order]= ts.p.sortorder;}
...
$.extend(ts.p.postData,prm);
```

where

```
prmNames: {page:"page",rows:"rows", sort: "sidx",order: "sord", search:"_search",
           nd:"nd", id:"id",oper:"oper",editoper:"edit",addoper:"add",
           deloper:"del", subgridid:"id", npage: null, totalrows:"totalrows"}
```

So to set `_search` parameter of URL one should set `search` parameter of jqGrid.

Look at [the following demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MultisearchFilterAtStart.htm). You can easy to verify using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) of [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) that the jqGrid from the page send HTTP GET with the following url:

```
http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MultisearchFilterAtStart1.json?filters=%7B%22groupOp%22%3A%22AND%22%2C%22rules%22%3A%5B%7B%22field%22%3A%22invdate%22%2C%22op%22%3A%22gt%22%2C%22data%22%3A%222007-09-06%22%7D%2C%7B%22field%22%3A%22invdate%22%2C%22op%22%3A%22lt%22%2C%22data%22%3A%222007-10-04%22%7D%2C%7B%22field%22%3A%22name%22%2C%22op%22%3A%22bw%22%2C%22data%22%3A%22test%22%7D%5D%7D&_search=true&nd=1297508504770&rows=10&page=1&sidx=id&sord=asc
```

So it do exactly what you need. The code of the demo contain the following code fragment:

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    url: 'MultisearchFilterAtStart1.json',
    datatype: "json",
    postData: {
        filters:'{"groupOp":"AND","rules":['+
                '{"field":"invdate","op":"gt","data":"2007-09-06"}'+
                ',{"field":"invdate","op":"lt","data":"2007-10-04"}'+
                ',{"field":"name","op":"bw","data":"test"}]}'
    },
    search:true,
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Great!! the very last snipped of code totally solved the misery - this - 
` jQuery('#' + block_id).jqGrid({
  url:loadUrl,
  mtype:'POST',
  postData:{block_id:block_id,
       filters:'{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"Cloud Upload ",
                "op":"cn","data":"costa"}]}'},
  search:true,
  autowidth:true,
  height: '100%',
  datatype: "json",
  // ..
  });`

Comment: [ran out of time on editing the previous comment] - when i put my search/filter params into the grid-init arguments, it totally made it all work. Thank you, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

@Oleg Oleg's answer works like a charm but just for the first time.

For me when I reload the grid, filters and search flag are not set up.
With the following code each time I reload the grid it also sends the filters and search flag.
I use server side sort and pagination.

I'm using:

```
jQuery("#myGrid").navGrid("#myPager", {search: true, refresh: true, edit: false, 
    add:false, del:false}, {}, {}, {}, {});
```

On the grid definition:

```
beforeRequest: function() {
    // filter to be added on each request
    var filterObj1 = {"field":"myField","op":"eq","data":"myValue"}; 
    var grid = jQuery("#myGrid");
    var postdata = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData');             
    if(postdata != undefined && postdata.filters != undefined ) {
        postdata.filters = jQuery.jgrid.parse(postdata.filters);
        //Remove if current field exists
        postdata.filters.rules = jQuery.grep(postdata.filters.rules, function(value) {
            if(value.field != 'myField')
                return value;
        });
        // Add new filters
        postdata.filters.rules.push(filterObj1);
    } else {
        jQuery.extend(postdata, {
            filters:  { 
                "groupOp":"AND",
                "rules":[filterObj1] 
            }
        });
        // more filters in the way: postdata.filters.rules.push(filterObj1);
    }
    postdata.filters = JSON.stringify(postdata.filters);
    postdata._search = true;
    return [true,''];
}
```

Comment: AS Oleg pointed out if you override prNames with your custom values you must modify code above accordingly.