# jqgrid first load filtering

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

I was wondering if there is a way for jqgrid to pass a certain value/string from a given view to the controller, I have a case where I would like to filter my records at the first load and then allow search. I tried to pass the value in the griddata function alongside the sid and sord ... but it would just pass that string as null, I found a couple of related posts but I couldnt utilize them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should just set `filters` property of the `postData` jqGrid parameter and set one more parameter `search:true`. Look at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973361/how-can-i-preserve-the-search-filters-in-jqgrid-on-page-reload/4977896#4977896) with [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MultisearchFilterAtStart.htm). One more [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272850/is-there-an-api-in-jqgrid-to-add-advanced-filters-to-post-data/5273385#5273385) shows how to construct the `filters` property.

Comment: Thanks Oleg for your guidance, the case that I have is a hidden field in the page that contains the value which will be filtered in one of my columns, so every page will have its own hidden field value and I will have to transfer that value to the controller from view... is there any way to solve that case?

Comment: @Sue: You can use `postData: {myParam: function() { return $("#myHiddenField").val(); }}`. In the case the additional parameter `myParam` with the current value from the field with `id="myHiddenField"` will be send to the controller **on every** grid load/refreshing. If the hidden field has an initial value it will be send at the page load.