# Preset the jqGrid filter text box through code

Tags: search, jqgrid

We are using jqGrid for ASP.Net version 3.6.6.0. We are facing a problem in search/filter as described below:

1. We have created a jqGrid using ASP.Net (C#) having column likes Name ,Status etc. There is a hyperlink on Name column.
2. We are able to  successfully populate the grid
3. User applies search on a column say “Name=’XYZ’” and grid is updated according to search results.
4. User clicks on Name link and is taken to details page of that Name.
5. Now when user clicks back from that details page ,search is lost.
6. We were able to persist the searched grid details using session however we are not able to set the searched text back in search text box.
   i.e we are not able to set the value “XYZ” in search text box of Name Column.

Need your help in knowing which property or method is to be used to set the Filter text box through code.

Comment: I recommend you to use more recent version of jqGrid. The 3.6.5 version (I am not sure that 3.6.6 exist) is more as one year old and for there are not so many people who have the old version in his archived. In any way if you would find a bug it will be really difficult to fix it. I recommend you to try with current version 4.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Advanced Searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching) the searching parameters are saved in the `postData.filters` property in [the JSON encoded format](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#options). If you use the [Single field searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching) another properties of the `postData` parameter of the jqGrid save the filter information: `searchField`, `searchString`, `searchOper`. So what you can to do is to same the filters in the cookie. To restore the searching filters you can examine the cookie and if needed extend the `postData` parameter with the corresponding properties (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492963/jqgrid-client-side-searching/4509018#4509018) for details).

If you want that the searching filters will be not only displayed if one opens the Searching Dialog you can set additionally the `search:true` parameter of the jqGrid.

I recommend you additionally read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973361/how-can-i-preserve-the-search-filters-in-jqgrid-on-page-reload/4977896#4977896) on the close question.