# Specify default filter in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I want to preload a set of filters on initial load of the grid. The reason for this is that I am planning to store the last selected filter in a session variable so the user will come back to the grid as he left it the last time.

I know there is an option to set defaultValue under editoptions for one column, but I am looking for a way to load the whole filter at once. (Not a function for each coulmn).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose that you use advanced searching for the filtering. The filter is nothing more as the value of `postData.filters`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5273385/315935) and [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MultisearchFilterAtStart.htm) from another [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4977896/315935) for details.

Moreover I would recommend you to read [the demo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8436273/315935) where I describe how to use `localStorage` to save some user preferences of the grid inclusive the searching filter. Moreover I describe why I think the usage of the `localStorage` the better way as the usage of cookies or session variables.

Comment: Thanks, Oleg. Just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

In the column options, add the defaultValue parameter inside the searchoptions option:

```
searchoptions:{ sopt:['eq'], defaultValue:"SomeValue" }
```