# Is it possible to filter jqGrid with a default colModel

Tags: jqgrid, filter

I have a problem how to make a default search based on Ship_via Column in the following demo [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/simplelocalgridwithsearchingtoolbarmultilpe1.htm) which was done by Oleg. I dont know how to do it as I am new to jqGrid. Please any one help me.

I will make it Clear Oleg. First of all When the page loads the grid will show like the following:In the following grid,it show all the results when page load,

[image: Default Multiselect grid]

But I need the grid in following way when the page loads,By default in Shipped via Column, FedEx option should be selected and grid should be loaded,We should not select by clicking on FedEx option and later we can change for search option.I want with this example not with the other examples

[image: Default Select]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what you mean under "default search".

If you need to display grid with *filtered data* you should read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4977896/315935) for the corresponding code example. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5273385/315935) shows how to build searching filter dynamically. [One more answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6884755/315935) shows how the initial filter could be displayed in the searching toolbar. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8436273/315935) shows how to save the filter in `localStorage` and reload the page at the next time with the same filter.

Comment: I just gave a brief explanation on it,please check it