# Is there any way to get the "full" URL of jquery jqGrid to maintain state of filters?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, filtering, query-string

I am using [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) and I have used the [advanced column search dialog](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aadvanced_searching) to filter on multiple columns.  I now want to "send" this URL to another person so they can see **exactly** what i see. The issue is that since this is all using ajax, the URL doesn't include the filter rules.

Is there a way i can have a "Permalink" link that will generate the current jqGrid URL including all advance filters so when i enter it on another person's browser it will includes those filters set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the question interesting. In general it's clear that the URL of the page which displays grid is not the same as URL used for Ajax requests to fill the grid content. Nevertheless under some restriction one can do provide a reasonable solution of the problem.

Let us we have HTML page which doesn't use and parameters or at least doesn't use the parameter with some specific name, like `filters`. We can use the URL option of the page to forward it to `postData.filters`. In the way the user who created some filter can add the filter to the URL. If the user will send the URL to somebody then opening of the URL will show *filtered* grid.

One can suggest many implementation ways of the approach. The implementation depends of cause from whether the filtering will take place of the client side or on the server. The usage of `loadonce: true` with loading the data from the server and filtering on the client is the special case which I find the mostly difficult. So I prepared small demo which works in the case

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/UrlFilter.htm) loads the data from the server and uses `loadonce: true` option. It displays initially unfiltered grid

[image]

If the user set some filter, for example the following one

[image]

then the grid fill display one filtered row:

[image]

Then the user can click the custom button in the navigator bar

[image]

It appends the `filters` option to the current URL. As the result [the new URL](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/UrlFilter.htm?filters=%7B%22groupOp%22:%22AND%22,%22rules%22:%5B%7B%22field%22:%22Name%22,%22op%22:%22cn%22,%22data%22:%221%22%7D%5D%7D) will contains

```
?filters=%7B"groupOp"%3A"AND"%2C"rules"%3A%5B%7B"field"%3A"Name"%2C"op"%3A"cn"%2C"data"%3A"1"%7D%5D%7D
```

part.

The code of the demo is only an example of the implementation. You can modify it to your requirements. The code which I used in the demo you will find below:

```js
// parse URL and get filters option if it exists
var urlOptions = window.location.href.split("?"), urlParams, filters, i, params;
if (urlOptions.length === 2) {
    urlParams = urlOptions[1].split("&");
    for (i=0; i<urlParams.length; i++) {
        params = urlParams[i].split("=");
        if (params.length === 2 && params[0] === "filters") {
            filters = decodeURIComponent(params[1]);
        }
    }
}

$.extend($.jgrid.search, {multipleSearch: true, multipleGroup: true});

$("#list").jqGrid({
    ... // some non-important options
    datatype: "json",
    loadonce: true,
    beforeRequest: function () {
        var $self = $(this), postData = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData");
        if (filters && !postData.filters) {
            // use filters from the URL if no other filter specified
            postData.filters = filters;
            $self.jqGrid("setGridParam", {search: true});
        }
    },
    loadComplete: function () {
        // disable custom button if no filter set
        var $self = $(this), postData = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData");
        if (postData.filters && filters !== postData.filters) {
            $("#addFilterToUrl").prop("disabled", false).removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
        } else {
            $("#addFilterToUrl").prop("disabled", true).addClass("ui-state-disabled");
        }

        if ($self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "loadonce") && $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "datatype") !== "local") {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $self.trigger("reloadGrid");
            }, 100);
        }
    }
}).jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager")
  .jqGrid("navButtonAdd", "#pager", {
      caption: "",
      title: "add filter to the current URL",
      id: "addFilterToUrl",
      buttonicon: "ui-icon-comment",
      onClickButton: function () {
          // append filter to the current URL
          var postData = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData");
          if (postData.filters) {
              window.location.href = window.location.href.split("?")[0] + "?" +
                  $.param({filters: postData.filters});
          }
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Built in not to my knowledge, but if you wanted to you could build that url yourself and then look for it when building the jqgrid and decode it and add those search values to the jqGrid.

The following post might give you a hand in how to access those parameters for the build of the url and then the rebuild in the link the other person would get.

[jqGrid clear search criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989786/jqgrid-clear-search-criteria)