# Does jqgrid have some functionality to use multiselect in toolbar search?

Tags: jqgrid

I need to make toolbar search with select filter, that give ability to chose several items for one column. Is it possible to do this in jqgrid?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible in the current version of jqGrid.

The option `multiple: true` can be used in [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editoptions) and it change the behavior of the form editing or the inline editing, but it will be ignored in the toolbar search.

Comment: Please, can someone advise me how can I do this functionality. I tried to add multiple select functionality in jqgrid code, but all my efforts lead to nothing! Maybe it's can be implement with some custom approach???

Comment: @Nik_eL: You can for example add your own select (dropdown) control **outside** of jqGrid (for example above it) and send the results of selection as a part of `postData` to the server (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928371/how-to-filter-the-jqgrid-data-not-using-the-built-in-search-filter-box/2928819#2928819). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974324/jqgrid-using-multiple-methods-to-filter-data/3979490#3979490 with the  http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CheckboxesWithVerticalHeaders1.htm demo.