# jqgrid hiding and displaying rows

Tags: jqgrid

I need help with filtering rows from jqgrid. I have a grid with large amount of data (title, address, names, some more related info) displayed and in the top i have a list with summary of names.

I need to convert this summary of names into checkboxes and if the user unselects a name, the corresponding rows should be removed from the grid. This was doable with multiple search option but the user wants a very simple checkbox and does not want to go through the steps of adding a filter.

Is there a way i can add the custom filters on select event of this custom checkboxes.

Please advise
Desai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correct you [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CheckboxesWithVerticalHeaders1.htm) which I created for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974324/jqgrid-using-multiple-methods-to-filter-data/3979490#3979490) is what you need. The demo shows how you can use `postData` parameter of jqGrid to filter the grid contain.

Comment: AWESOME!!!   i need something very similar to this.. i will attempt to try the variation by myself. i will start with all the checkboxes checked and when u uncheck a checkbox the corresponding row should be removed from master grid. THANK YOU SOOO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP!!! JQUERY ROCKS!!!

Comment: @Desai: You are welcome! I though also that in your case selecting of all checkboxes are the best choice for start.