# How to use setColumns() in JQGrid?

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

Hi I wish to set the Column values for my grid using setColumns().  Now I don't know how to use the said function.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks

-Jason

---

I already know how to use columnChooser.  But what I want to happen is to set the grid depends on per users preference.  I mean, per customer has its own default columns to be displayed that is saved in the database.

So now, once the page load per customer, the columns for that customer will be the one to be shown on the screen.  So I need something that can do this when the page loads.  And so far the only option is setColumn (even setcolumn is not the best option).

Do you have anything to offer?

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [setColumn](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:show_hide_columns) method is old and is [not more supported](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:upgrade_from_3.8_to_4.0.0) started with jqGrid 4.0.0. You can include `grid.setcolumns.js` from the `plugins` directory to use [setColumn](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:show_hide_columns), but I don't recommend you to use it.

You should use more powerful [columnChooser](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods#column_chooser) method instead. I recommend you to look at [the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901210/is-there-a-full-working-example-for-a-jqgrid-columnchooser/5901459#5901459) which describes how to use [columnChooser](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods#column_chooser).