# jqGrid Basic Column Chooser

Tags: jqgrid, column-chooser

jqGrid has a column chooser functionality as like described here:

```
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods
```

and a demonstration from @Oleg:

http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooser.htm

However its too complex for my needs. Is there any simple way as like FlexGrid's show-hide columns choosing functionality:

http://flexigrid.info/

You can check Example 1. Columns can be shown and hide by clicking columns. I don't want to same thing but it would be great just clicking somewhere at or near columns and choosing just columns to show or hide.

Any ideas?

*PS:* I want a basic show-hide column field not a complex screen that opens and people selects many options on them. It should be build on table as like Flexigirid. users click checkboxes and thats all.

Comment: In [my demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooser.htm) from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901210/is-there-a-full-working-example-for-a-jqgrid-columnchooser/5901459#5901459) there are only one call of `navButtonAdd` method add custom button to the navigator bar and it defines the `onClickButton` action as `grid.jqGrid('columnChooser');`. Can be the code more simple? Additionally it demonstrates which CSS and JS files should be included and in which order.

Comment: @Oleg I tried to explain more. I want a small screen actually same with Flexigrid. If you want I can explain more what I want, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but **you can't have the same look in one software product like you know in another one**.

Do you can configure flexigrid so that it looks like jqGrid? Do you can that iPhone looks like Windows Phone or Mac OS X looks like Windows? Every software product has its own design and the set of features.

The `columnCooser` are based on the multiselect widget and allows you to show or hide any columns or reorder columns with respect of drag & drop. flexigrid has *another* implementation of the features.

If you want to use some *free* open soure product you should understand the features and the possibilities which provide *the product* and just use there.

Comment: thanks for your comment but I should explain more. I don't want to have same ability with another product. I want to have same feature that other grids usually have. I examined other grid implementations and many of them use show-hide column functionality as like Flexi Grid. So that's why I asked does jqGrid has same opportinity or not. Not like spesific features between Windows and Linux as like common features that others have.

Comment: @kamaci: For me the feature is the ability to hide or to show some columns and the ability to change the column order. The implementations are different in the way where the user should click to see the dialog which allows to choose the visible columns. For me personally the way in jqGrid is more intuitive. Everybody knows the toolbar. I find not intuitive to hover some special place in the column header to be able to see the button which can be used to choose the columns. The tastes are different.