# How to get the list of columns after adding and removing columns in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

After I add and remove columns in jqgrid, how do I get a list of the columns that are displayed?

When I call the method:

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('columnChooser',{ "msel_opts": $.ui.multiselect.defaults, "done": function (permut) {
        var colnames = $("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');
  }
});
```

Colnames returns back with the original set of columns and not the updated list after the columns have been removed or added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did't test this, but I suppose that the problem that you should first call

```
$("#list").jqGrid("remapColumns", permut, true);
```

inside of `done` event handler and then test the `colModel` elements for `hidden:true` property. You should have now not only the correct value of the `hidden` property, but the correct order of columns too.

Additionally I see no need to use `"msel_opts": $.ui.multiselect.defaults` option. Probably you have some other problems which you try to fix. I recommend you verify that you included all dependencies of the `columnChooser` correctly. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901210/is-there-a-full-working-example-for-a-jqgrid-columnchooser/5901459#5901459) for details.