# Add Remove Column Handler on jqGrid ColumnChooser

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, multi-select

I'm using the [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajqgriddocs) [columnChooser](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajquery_ui_methods), like so:

```
    jQuery(grid).jqGrid(
        'navButtonAdd',
        pagerDiv,
        {
            caption: "Columns",
            buttonicon: "ui-icon-newwin",
            title: "Hide/Show Columns",
            onClickButton: function () {
                $(this).jqGrid('columnChooser', {
                    done: function (perm) {
                        if (perm) {
                            $(this).jqGrid('remapColumns', perm, true);
                        }
                    },
                    modal: true,
                    width: 400,
                    height: 300,
                    classname: 'column-chooser-select'
                });
            }
        }
    );
```

and was wondering if there was a way to specify an event handler on the columnChooser (using the [jQuery UI Multiselect](http://www.quasipartikel.at/multiselect/) plugin that comes w/ jqGrid) that fires any time a column is either added or removed.  So I guess it's a two-part question:

1. does the jQuery UI Multiselect support such a thing?
2. if so, is there a way to hook it up without altering the jqGrid source?

A bit of background on what I'm trying to achieve:

My default grid configuration hides many columns.  Some of these columns are not populated from the db - they are obscure, rarely used data elements that if populated would dramatically decrease the query execution performance (multiple joins involving tables with 100 million plus records).

Should a user pick one of these columns for display i'd like to warn them that another roundtrip to the server is required and it could take a while - and give them the option to cancel the column addition.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I understand your problem and find your question interesting, so I wrote the demo for you which shows how one can solve the problem.

[columnChooser](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods#column_chooser) uses jQuery UI Multiselect plugin internally which uses jQuery UI Sortable. So I suggest to use [sortreceive](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.7.1/Sortable#event-receive) event of the jQuery UI Sortable to catch the information needed.

The code can be the following

```
$("#grid").jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#pager', {
    caption: "",
    buttonicon: "ui-icon-calculator",
    title: "Choose columns",
    onClickButton: function () {
        $(this).jqGrid('columnChooser');
        $("#colchooser_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id) + " ul.selected")
            .bind("sortreceive", function (event, ui) {
                alert('column "' + ui.item.text() + '" is choosed');
            });
        $("#colchooser_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id) + " ul.available a.action")
            .click(function () {
                alert('column "' + $(this).parent().text() + '" is choosed');
            });

    }
});
```

See the demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooser8.htm).

The code bind 'click' event on the "+" for the *initial* list of the columns which was in the column chooser at the initialization time of the dialog. I think it would be sufficient for you. If needed you can easy modify the code to support the 'click' on the "+" for the columns which will be removed from the left list during the work with the `columnChooser`.

I almost forget to mention that I used in the demo improved version of the `columnChooser` (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9688942/315935)), but my above suggestion works with the original version of `columnChooser` too.

Comment: Thanks Oleg.  This is perfect.

Comment: Which javascript plugins are required for this ?

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: the directory `plugins` of jqGrid contains `ui.multiselect.css` and `ui.multiselect.js` wich are required. Moreover the jQuery UI is required too.

Comment: I used the same but now it is not showing proper way. It is showing very big columns and not multiple options, Please provide a sample code with complete functionality if you have.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: The reference to [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooser8.htm) you will find in my answer.

Comment: @Oleg I want to change the page size of info Page where the selected row is displayed, how can i do that ?

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. What is "page size" in the `columnChooser` dialog? What you mean under the "info Page"?

Comment: @Oleg info page means in `JQgrid` the tag which we are using for showing the row in the popup page. Now I want to change the `height` and `width` parameter of that info page.

Comment: @Oleg what if I want to make some of the columns only selected at the time of loading the page for the selectable columns.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: `columnChooser` selects automatically the visible columns. I'm not understand what additional columns you want select. In my answer I shown some examples how you can use jQuery UI Sortable events to add custom behavior in `columnChooser`. You can implement other events to implement any other behaviors which you need.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the below code in JqGrid for column chooser plug-in. when i tick the **select All** check box in the grid. I want to exclude particular column ( by default it should not display in my grid).
I used hidden=True property in col model. buy  i want to handle these in column chooser also.

```
function Properties_Columnchooser() {
    $('#btn_setColumns').click(function () {
        jQuery('#grid-tableProperties').jqGrid('columnChooser',{
        "shrinkToFit" : true,
        "autowidth" : true,
        done : function(perm) {
            w = $(window).width();
            // alert('done ' + w);
            if (perm) 
               {
                this.jqGrid("remapColumns", perm, true);
                 this.setGridWidth(w - 30, true);

                $('.ui-search-input').show();
            } 
             else 
            {
            }
        }
    }
);
    });
}
```