# Use JQuery to loop through the li from the ColumnChooser's multiselect ul.selected tag?

Tags: jqgrid

I saw this link at [Add Remove Column Handler on jqGrid ColumnChooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439072/add-remove-column-handler-on-jqgrid-columnchooser) .

I wonder how to use this JQuery syntax to loop through the < li >< /li > list to get the display text...

```
    $("#colchooser_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id) + " ul.selected")
        //.bind("sortreceive", function (event, ui) {
        //    alert('column "' + ui.item.text() + '" is choosed');
        //});
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.each()`

http://api.jquery.com/each/

```
var id = $.jgrid.jqID(this.id);

$("#colchooser_" + id + " ul.selected li").each(function() {
  console.log( $(this).text() );
});
```

That would log out the content of each `<li>`'s display text.