# jqGrid show/hide columns dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to create a dialog to enable/disable columns for my jqGrid. There was a [module for this](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:show_hide_columns), but his is no longer supported as of jqGrid 4.x.

Is there a replacement for this module, I did not find one. Anything already existing I could reuse - or what would be the easiest way to realize it?

From the jqGrid documentation ([here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:show_hide_columns)), this is what I need:

[image: Show/Hide columns]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [columnChooser](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods#column_chooser). I would recommend you to use modified code of the method which I published in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9688942/315935) (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooser5__.htm)). It makes Column Chooser Dialog resizable. You can just include the code with `$.jgrid.extend({columnChooser : function ... });` after `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` or `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` and overwrite the original version of `columnChooser` with the modified version.

Comment: Can you address the issue we're facing as mentioned at the end of the thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687201/jqgrid-column-chooser-modal-overlay/9688942. The last line in 'columnChooser' extension is causing error and commenting it seems to work fine!

Comment: @HemantTank: Sorry, but I'm not sure what you do. First of all, yo references really old questions. **Which version of jqGrid you use and which fork?** The problem with `selector.data('dialog').uiDialog` is solved since a lot ot time. The problem was in the usge **more recent** version of jQuery UI (published after I posted the old answer). So, what you do exactly?