# How to inject additional html codes to jqGrid's column-chooser dialog?

Tags: jqgrid

Is it possible to inject additional html codes to the dialog of the jqGrid Column Chooser dialog?  If so then what's the best way to do it?

```
$('#jqgridTest').columnChooser({
    title: "Saved Builds",
    //Inject some html codes here??
});
```

Comment: what exactly you want to change in `columnChooser` dialog? Which HTML fragment you need to inject? An example could explains many opened questions.

Comment: Adding a drop-down selection and another button to the columnChooser dialog box.

Comment: I still don't understand what exactly you need. Where you need add "a drop-down selection" for example and where add the button? An picture could be helpful. Do you need have the `columnChooser` dialog box resizable (see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9688942/315935)) or you use original code from jqGrid? I don't understand where you have the problem in adding HTML eleemnts to the dialog.

Comment: The example is already provided in the original post above.  I don't see how to inject a drop-down selection and inject a button into the columnChooser script for it to show up on the Column-Chooser dialog box.

Comment: If **the position** of HTML fragment in the Column-Chooser dialog box not important for you I can post an example which shows how you can modify the dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can examine the HTML structure of columnCooser dialog you will see the following

[image]

So you can make any modifications of the columnCooser dialog which you need. You need just insert HTML fragment which you need on the place which you need. For example to insert "Hi!" button I used the following JavaScript code of `onClickButton`:

```js
onClickButton: function () {
    var $button = $('<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false" type="button"><span class="ui-button-text">Hi!</span></button>');
    $(this).jqGrid('columnChooser');
    $("#colchooser_" + this.id +
        " ~ div.ui-dialog-buttonpane > div.ui-dialog-buttonset");
        //.prepend($button);
    $button.click(function () {
        alert('"Hi!" button is clicked!');
    });
}
```

As the result (see the corresponding demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooser9.htm)) one will have something like the picture above after clicking on the "Hi!" button:

[image]