# jqGrid group column with columnChooser

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I use `columnChooser` plugin like [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooser5__.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9688942/315935), but I want to customize it more, like hide column in group not in each column like that.
Is there any way to do that with jqGrid?
Many thanks for help

Comment: Which "group" you mean? In general you can fill the dialog with any information which you need. In the case you will need to use `done` which calls `hideCol` and `showCol` based on the results. In any way you should describe more detailed what you want to do.

Comment: For example, is this example above we have 8 column in columnchooser popup. I want to group Client and date in to 1 line. whenever I click that line, column client and date have to hide