# Difficulties in column chooser functionality of jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

i am using jquery version 4.x and i have implemented column chooser on my jqgrid

Now when i click on "Remove All" link button or "Add All" link button then in throws following error in console :

"**$("ul.selected").sortable is not a function**"

Now when i click on (-) button to remove field from list, it throws following error :

"**$(this).parent().draggable is not a function**"

i have implemented jqgrid in following .js file :

```
function partygrid()
{
        $("#partylist").jqGrid({
            url: sitepath + 'party/grid',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',
            height:'220',
            colNames:["party_name","party_type_name","status","action"],
            colModel :[ 
                          {name:'party_name', index:'party_name',width:120,editable:false,editoptions:{size:20},editrules:{required:true,number:false,maxlength:10}},
                          {name:'party_type', index:'party_type',width:120,editable:false,editoptions:{size:20},editrules:{required:true,number:false,maxlength:10}},
                          {name:'is_active', index:'is_active',search:false},
                          {name:'act', index:'act',width:50,search:false}
                       ],
            pager: '#partytoolbar',
            rowNum:10,
            rowList:[10,20,30],
            sortname: 'party_id',
            sortorder: 'desc',
            viewrecords: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            gridview: true,
            multiselect: true,
            autoresize:true,
            autowidth: true,
            editurl: sitepath + 'party/grid',
            toolbar: [true,"top"],
            gridComplete: function () 
            {
                 var grid = jQuery("#partylist");
                 var ids = grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                 for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) 
                 {  

                 }
            },
            caption: 'Party List'
         });
         jQuery("#partylist").jqGrid('navGrid','#partytoolbar',{view:false,edit:false,add:false,del:false,search: false});
         jQuery("#partylist").jqGrid('navButtonAdd','#partytoolbar',
                 { 
                     caption: "Columns", 
                     title: "Reorder Columns", 
                     onClickButton : function ()
                     { 
                        jQuery("#partylist").jqGrid('columnChooser'); 
                     } 
                 });
}
```

I have implemented column chooser in above snippet.

but facing above mentioned two errors.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thnx in advance

Comment: jquery 4.0? whats that? jqueryui and jquery proper arent past 2.0 yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should look in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5901459/315935) and verify that you included *all* CSS and JavaScript files in correct order and from the correct source. It seems to me that you don't included jQuery UI `jquery-ui.min.js` which is not required for the base jqGrid, but is do requited for `ui.multiselect.js`  and the [columnChooser](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods#column_chooser).

Additionally I would recommend you to use modified version of `columnCooser` like I described it in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9688942/315935). I hope that [my suggestions](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/making-columnchooser-really-resizable/#p25823) will be included in the next release of jqGrid.