# Confused about jQuery handling of my data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

So likely not the best title but that's what I think is going on.

I wrote [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862317/jqgrid-boolean-or-enumeration-dropdown-filtering-for-columns) wanting to populate a dropdownlist in my jqGrid so the user could pick from the available selections for filtering.  The solution provided works in one instance but not in another.  The first type it retrieves the data (for the column header dropdown filter) my stack trace looks like so:

```
callback() jquery-1.6.2.js (line 7947)
_ = readystatechange

done() jquery-1.6.2.js (line 7183)
status = 200
statusText = "success"
responses = Object { text="["Cake", "Sugar", "Waffle"]" }
headers = "Server: ASP.NET Develop...: 22\nConnection: Close\n"

resolveWith() jquery-1.6.2.js (line 1008)
context = Object { url="/IceCream/AvailableConeTypes", isLocal=false, more...}
args = [ Object { readyState=4, responseTExt="["Cake", "Sugar", "Waffle"]", more...} "success"]

complete() jquery...src.js(line 3591)
res = Object { readyState=4, responseText="["Cake", "Sugar", "Waffle"]", more...}
status = "success"

myBuildSelect() Cone (line 75)
data = Object { readyState=4, responseText="["Cake", "Sugar", "Waffle"]", more...}
```

the second time when this is called (for the jqGrid toolbar filter dialog that allows you to construct multiple AND/OR filters) the stack trace is slightly different:

```
callback() jquery-1.6.2.js (line 7947)
_ = readystatechange

done() jquery-1.6.2.js (line 7168)
status = 200
statusText = "success"
responses = Object { text="["Cake", "Sugar", "Waffle"]" }
headers = "Server: ASP.NET Develop...: 22\nConnection: Close\n"

resolveWith() jquery-1.6.2.js (line 1008)
context = Object { elem=, options={...} }
args = [ "["Cake", "Sugar", "Waffle"]", "success", Object { readyState=4, responseText="["Cake", "Sugar", "Waffle"]", more...} ]

success() jquery...src.js(line 5099)
data ="["Cake", "Sugar", "Waffle"]"
status = "success"

myBuildSelect() Cone (line 75)
data = ="["Cake", "Sugar", "Waffle"]"
```

I'm confused as to what's going on here.  Looking at the jquery-1.6.2.js file at the referenced lines, I see that in the first instance it is executes the line:

```
deferred.resolveWith { callbackContext, [success, statusText, jqXHR] );  (line 7168)
```

and in the second instance it executes the line:

```
completeDeferred.resolveWith( callbackContext, [ jqXHR, statusText] );  (line 7183)
```

Seems like things are being cached or handled differently when the call is made to that controller action the second time.  I can post additional code if that is helpful, but it is essentially what I wrote in my earlier question along with Oleg's solution.  Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would recommend you to use the last 4.1.2 version of jqGrid instead of very old 4.0.0 version (the line numbers of the `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` which you included in the question are from the v4.0.0). The version 4.1.2 includes many bug fixes.

The reason on the problem which you have is the following. One can use `complete` or `success` and `error` event handlers of the [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to process the server response. The old jqGrid code used the `complete` event handler everywhere. It was not the best way, so in many places *but not everywhere* (!!!) the jqGrid code was changed and not mostly `success` and `error` handlers are used. Inside of `complete` handler the `data` parameter has the `string` type (in JSON format in your case). So one need make additional call of [$.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to convert the data to the object. Inside of `success` the `data` are already processed corresponds to the "Content-Type" HTTP header of the server response and the `dataType` parameter of the `$.ajax`.

One can find in the source code of jqGrid, that the `buildSelect` will be called in [filterToolbar](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/grid.custom.js#L325) inside of `complete` handler and it will be called in [createEl](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/grid.common.js#L355) inside of `success` handler. It's the problem which you has.

I recommend you to post the description of the problem as the bug report in the [trirand forum](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/) or I can do it for you.

As the workaround I suggest to modify the `buildSelect` function, which I suggested in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862317/jqgrid-boolean-or-enumeration-dropdown-filtering-for-columns/6863704#6863704) on your previous question, to the following:

```
my.buildSelect = function(data) {
    var response = typeof(data) === "string" ?
                       jQuery.parseJSON(data.responseText):
                       data,
        s = '<select>', i, l, ri;

    if (response && response.length) {
        for (i=0, l=response.length; i<l; i += 1) {
            ri = response[i];
            s += '<option value="' + ri + '">' + ri + '</option>';
        }
    }
    return s + '</select>';
};
```

So I suggest to test the type of the `data` input parameter. After the changes the code should work in all situations and it will still work if jqGrid will be changed to use the `success` handler instead of `complete` handler everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your encouragement and insight Oleg.  I got this working with your help.  It can be very difficult to debug these things (at least for me) when it gets down into the weeds of code I didn't write and don't really understand all that well.  Kudos to you for being so well versed in jqGrid and jQuery.  Thanks!

Comment: @itsmatt: You are welcome! And thanks for the good words addressed to me.