# jqGrid Switch a field to dropdown from text

Tags: jqgrid

Ive got a jqGrid where i have a some columns and 1 of the columns is a dropdownlist(select) populated from database.

What i want is : When im not in editmode column with dropdowns just have to show text which have to be taken from query, and when im in edit mode it should show dropdown list.

exactly like here: http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html    go into row editing/input tipyes

here is the code for my grid:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lastsel;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("ConstructSelect")', function (data) {
            setupGrid(data);
        });
    });
    function setupGrid(data) {
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery("#list").jqGrid({

                url: '@Url.Action("GetStoreList")',
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'GET',
                colNames: ['Butiks kategori', 'Butik Navn', 'By', 'Sælger'],

                colModel: [
                        { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 50 },
                        { name: 'Butiks Kategori', index: 'StoreId', width: 200, edittype: 'text', align: 'center', editable: false },
                        { name: 'Buttiks Navn', index: 'StoreName', width: 200, edittype: 'text', align: 'center', editable: false },
                        { name: 'Country', index: 'Country', width: 80, sortable: true, editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: data }}],


                onSelectRow: function (id) {
                    if (id && id !== lastsel) {
                        jQuery('#list').jqGrid('restoreRow', lastsel);
                        jQuery('#list').jqGrid('editRow', id, true);
                        lastsel = id;

                    }
                },
                editurl: '@Url.Action("GridSave")',
                rowNum: 50000,
                rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
                pager: '#page',
                sortname: 'Id',
                sortorder: "desc",
                viewrecords: true,
                height: "500px",
                imgpath: '/scripts/themes/base/images'
            });
            jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', "#page", { edit: false, add: false, del: false });
        });
    }
</script>
```

P.S. Ill link code as soon as i am back home

**UPDATED**: Thanks for an answer, im new to jq, so im making alot of mistakes ofc., but now im back to where i was before, the dropdownlist is not populated with data. i cleaned up the code as u said, so it looks like this now:

btw. The ConstructSelect return a list of Strings

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetStoreList")',
        ajaxSelectOptions: { type: "POST", dataType: "json" },
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['Butiks kategori', 'Butik Navn', 'By', 'Sælger'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Kategori', index: 'Kategori', width: 50, key: false},
            { name: 'Navn', index: 'Navn', align: 'center', editable: false },
            { name: 'By', index: 'By', align: 'center', editable: false },
            { name: 'Sælger', index: 'Sælger', editable: true, edittype: "select",
                editoptions: { dataUrl: '@Url.Action("ConstructSelect")',
                buildSelect: function (data) {
                    var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data.responseText);
                    var s = '<select>';
                    if (response && response.length) {
                        for (var i = 0, l = response.length; i < l; i++) {
                            var ri = response[i];
                            s += '<option value="' + ri + '">' + ri + '</option>';
                        }
                    }
                    return s + "</select>";
                }
            }
        }],
        onSelectRow: function (id) {
            if (id && id !== lastsel) {
                jQuery('#list').jqGrid('restoreRow', lastsel);
                jQuery('#list').jqGrid('editRow', id, true);
                lastsel = id;
            }
        },
        editurl: '@Url.Action("GridSave")',
        rowNum: 50000,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
        pager: '#page',
        sortname: 'Id',
        sortorder: "desc",
        viewrecords: true,
        height: "900px"
    });
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', "#page", {edit:false, add:false, del:false});
});
```

Okay, slight modifications was needed to get it working :

```
var response = typeof(data) === "string" ? jQuery.parseJSON(data.responseText):data;
```

aparently u have to tell buildselect that the data u want to modify is String

But i still have the problem that it doesnt show from begining which sellers is already selected!

Okay after restart it mysticly worked... it is solved now

Comment: About the problem with `typeof(data) === "string"`: you are right. The problem I already described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873242/confused-about-jquery-handling-of-my-data/6873971#6873971). See additionally [my bug report](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/all-usage-of-buildselect-should-be-inside-of-ajax-success/#p24174) and [the fix](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/baa2b502ec3478bd5cf828e5d0c6e305601276da). In the new version of jqGrid the `data` parameter will be already array of strings and you will not need to call `jQuery.parseJSON`.

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do is to use

```
editoptions: { dataUrl: '@Url.Action("ConstructSelect")' }
```

instead of

```
editoptions: { value: data }
```

Depend on the format of the output of the action `ConstructSelect` you can need to use an additional property `buildSelect` of the `editoptions`. jqGrid expected that the server response on the HTTP 'GET' request of `dataUrl` will be HTML fragment which represent `<select>`. For example:

```
<select>
    <option value="de">Germany</option>
    <option value="us">USA</option>
</select>
```

If the server return other formatted data, like JSON data

```
["Germany","USA"]
```

or

```
[{"code":"de","display":"Germany"},{"code":"us","display":"USA"}]
```

you can write JavaScript function which convert the server response to the HTML fragment of the `<select>` and set the value of the property `buildSelect` to the function.

In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101116/asp-net-mvc-post-call-returning-string-need-help-with-format-for-jqgrid/4102155#4102155) you will find an example of the function.

If your action support only HTTP POST and no GET you will have to use `ajaxSelectOptions: { type: "POST" }` parameter additionally, to overwrite the type of the corresponding `ajax` requests. In the same way you can overwrite other `ajax` parameters. For example you can use

```
ajaxSelectOptions: { type: "POST", dataType: "json"}
```

(defaults are `type : "GET"` and `dataType: "html"`)

Some other small remarks to the code:

- you should not place `$(document).ready(function () {` inside of another `$(document).ready(function () {`.
- You use `'Id'` instead of `'id'`. So jqGrid **will not find** the `id` property. You can a) rename 
  `'Id'` to `'id'` b) include additional parameter `jsonReader: {id: 'Id'}` c) include additional property `key: true` in the definition of the column `'Id'`. Any from the ways will solve the described problem.
- You can remove default properties like `edittype: 'text'`, `sortable: true` or `editable: false`. See [jqGrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options) which describes the default values of all `colModel` properties.
- You should remove `imgpath` parameter of jqGrid. The parameter is not exist since many many versions of jqGrid (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:upgrade_from_3.4.x_to_3.5#options)).