# How to make jqGrid dynamically populate options list based on row data

Tags: dynamic, jqgrid

I am using jQrid version 3.8.1 with inline editing and each row in the grid has several dropdown lists to populate. When the user edits the row, I need to do an AJAX query to get the values for each of these lists. I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413905/jqgrid-populate-select-control-on-row-edit) regarding how to do that. It appears that the `dataUrl` and `buildSelect` features are the standard answer here. There are a few issues I can't figure out though:

1. The row the user is editing has a value that must be passed into the `dataUrl` value. For example, say each row contains a field called "SpecialValue" and that for row 1, SpecialValue = 100. The `dataUrl` field for row 1 would be "http://my.services.com?SpecialValue=100". How do I do that?
2. Each row in the grid has about 10 select boxes that need to be populated. For efficiency reasons, I don't want to make 10 separate AJAX calls. It would be much better to make one call to get all the data, split it up, and fill each select box accordingly. Is that possible? I tried doing this inside `onSelectRow` but the grid ended up ignoring the values I put in there (I'm guessing do the ordering of the events that fire when you edit a row).

### Edit:

After reading Oleg's answers and working on it more, it's clear to me that using `dataUrl` and `buildSelect` are not going to work well for me. The version of jqGrid I'm using doesn't support using `dataUrl` the way I would need. And even if it did I don't want to send multiple separate requests for each dropdown list.

I've decided to do one request when `gridComplete` fires to pull all the data needed for all dropdown lists into a single JSON structure. Then when the user selects a row to do inline editing, I will populate each list in the row from that JSON structure (the code below uses the getSelectValuesFromJSON() function for that--I don't give its definition but you can imaging it looks through the structure and gets an appropriate list of values to but in the list box).

I have a few candidate solutions but I'm not 100% happy with either one.

**Solution 1**:

Inside `onSelectRow`, I call `editRow` overriding the on `oneditfunc` to get the data out of the grid that I need. Assume that the value in `Field1` is required to get the values to be put into the list in `Field2`.

```js
onSelectRow: function (index, status, e) {
    jQuery('#my_grid').jqGrid('editRow', index, true, function(rowId) {
        var f1Val = $('#my_grid').jqGrid('getCell', index, 'Field1');
        var selectVals = getSelectValuesFromJSON(f1Val); //gets data out of previously loaded JSON structure
        var select = $('#my_grid').find('tr[id="' + index + '"] td[aria-describedby="my_grid_Field2"] select');
        _.each(selectVals, function(selectVal) {
            $(select).append($("<option></option>").attr("value", selectVal).text(selectVal));
        });
    });
}
```

This works but I'm hesitant about the line

```js
var select = $('#my_grid').find('tr[id="' + index + '"] td[aria-describedby="my_grid_Field2"] select');
```

which relies on this `aria-describedby` attribute that I don't know much about. Seems hacky and brittle.

**Solution 2**:

Make use of `beforeSelectRow` to dynamically change the model of the Field2 column when the user selects a row.

```js
beforeSelectRow: function(index, e) {
    var f1Val = getGridCellValue('#my_grid', index, 'Field1');
    var values = getSelectValuesFromJSON(f1Val); //gets data out of previously loaded JSON structure
    var valStr = "";
    _.each(values, function(value) {
        valStr += value + ":" + value + ";"
    });
    jQuery('#grid_pipes').setColProp('Field2', { editoptions: { value: valStr } });
    return true;
}
```

This also works but I'm not sure about whether or not this is really a good idea. Is it valid to dynamically change the model of a column like that? What if the user has several rows selected at the same time? Isn't there only one model for a column? What would that mean?

To answer some of Oleg's questions, the `dataType` has been set to a function that uses $.ajax to post data to the server. I think I read that's not the recommended approach anymore. I inherited this code so I'm not sure why it was done that way but it probably won't change unless there is a really compelling reason.

The `loadonce` boolean is not specified so I guess that means it defaults to `false`.

Here is an abbreviated version of the column model (nothing terribly out of the ordinary):

```js
colModel: [
    { name: 'PK', index: 'PK', hidden: true, editable: true, sortable: true, search: true },
    { name: 'Field1', index: 'Field1', hidden: true, editable: true, sortable: true, search: true },
    { name: 'Field2', index: 'Field2', sortable: false, editable: true, search: false, edittype: "select", editoptions: {} },
    { name: 'Field3', index: 'Field3', sortable: false, editable: true, search: false, edittype: "select", editoptions: {} },
    ...
]
```

Comment: You asked two questions in one post. The answer on the first question is relatively easy and I can post my answer, but the second problem can't solved so easy especially if you need to generate *individual* selects in every row.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, I would definitely be interested to get whatever input you can provide on either or both items.

Comment: Please write short comment to inform that you added new information in the text of your question. Only in the case other people who wrote his answers or wrote comments will be informed about it. I found pure accidentally that you made the changes. Additionally I recommend you to add `javascript` or `jquery` tag to your questions to have more colors in the code or to include `<!-- language: lang-js -->` before the code. I will incude the comments and you will see more colors in the code.

Comment: I posted **UPDATED** part in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't wrote which version of jqGrid you use currently, but `dataUrl` can be defined as callback function with `(rowid, value, name)` parameters, which have to return the URL which you can build dynamically based on the information. The feature exist starting with v4.5.3 (see [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.3/js/grid.common.js#L354)). You can use `getCell`, `getRowData` or `getLocalRow` inside of the callback to get the data from another columns of the row. Thus you can solve your first problem relatively easy.

You second question seems to me absolutely independent from the first one. It's better to separate such questions in different posts to allow the searching engine better to index the information and so to help other people to find it.

There are no simple way how to solve the second problem, but one can sure suggest a solution, but one have to know much more details what you do and how you do. How you start inline editing (do you use `inlineNav`, `formatter: "actions"` or you call `editRow` directly)? Which version of jqGrid (till version 4.7), [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) or [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) you use? How the columns with selects are defined in `colModel`? Which `datatype` you use and whether `loadonce: true` you use? I recommend you to post *separate question with the information*.

**UPDATE:** If you have to use old version of jqGrid then you can't generate `dataUrl` full dynamically, but because you need to add only `SpecialValue=100"` part to the URL you can follow the trick which I described in many my old answers (the first one was probably [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8150307/315935), but the choice on property names which asked the user could be misunderstood). You can use `ajaxSelectOptions.data` which will define the `data` parameters of jQuery.ajax request. The problem only that you can define *only one `ajaxSelectOptions.data` property*. So you can add the following **jqGrid option**:

```js
ajaxSelectOptions: {
    data: {
        SpecialValue: function () {
            var rowid = $myGrid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow");
            return $myGrid.jqGrid("getCell", rowid, "SpecialValue");
        }
    }
}
```

(`$myGrid` is something like `$("#grid")`)

**UPDATED:** You used unknown functions `getSelectValuesFromJSON`, `getLookupValuesFromJSON` in the updated part of your question. Both of there seems to use **synchronous** Ajax request which is not good. Moreover you set `editoptions.value` for *only one* `Field2` instead of setting *all* selects.

```js
onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
    var $myGrid = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: "someUrl",
        dataType: "json";
        data: {
            specialValue: $myGrid.jqGrid("getCell", rowid, "Field1")
        },
        success: function (data) {
            // for example response data have format:
            // { "Field2": ["v1", "v2", ...], "Field3": ["v3", "v4", ...] }
            var filed, str;
            for (filed in data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(filed)) {
                    str = $.map(data[filed], function (item) {
                                return item + ":" + item
                            }).join(";");
                    $myGrid.jqGrid("setColProp", filed, {
                        editoptions: {
                            value: str
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            $myGrid.jqGrid("editRow", rowid, true);
        }
    });
}
```

Nevertheless the "Solution 2" is more close to what I would recommend you. It's not really important whether to use `onSelectRow` or `beforeSelectRow`. You can make **asynchronous** Ajax request to the server which returns information for **all select** which you need. **After you get the response** from the server (inside of `success` callback) you can set `editoptions.value` for all selects and only then you can start `editRow`. In the way you will be sure that editing of the line will use row specific options in all select.

Some additional remarks. I recommend you to verify `gridview: true` option in the grid. Additionally I suspect that you fill the grid in not full correct way because you have hidden `PK` column and you use `index` instead of `rowid` as the first parameter of `beforeSelectRow` and `onSelectRow`. It's very important to understand that the current implementation of jqGrid **always assign `id` attribute on every row (`<tr>` element) of the grid**. So you *have to* provide `id` information in every item of input data. If you want *to display* the id information to the user (and so to have column in `colModel` with the primary key) then you should just include `key: true` property in the column definition. For example you can add `key: true` to the definition of `PK` column and so you will have `rowid` (or `index` in your case) with the same value like `PK`. It simplify many parts of code. For example jqGrid send `id` parameter in the  editing request to the server. It's practical to have `PK` in the request. Moreover if you use `repeatitems: false` format of `jsonReader` the you can include `id: "PK"` in the `jsonReader` instead of having hidden `PK` column. It informs jqGrid to get rowid from `PK`. jqGrid will save `PK` in `id` attribute of `<tr>` and you will don't need to have additional `<td style="display:none">` with the same information in the grid.

The last remark. I would strictly recommend you to update the retro version jqGrid 3.8.1 to some more recent version, for example to [free jqGrid](https://github.com/orgs/free-jqgrid/dashboard). Even if you would use no features (like [Font Awesome](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Using-Font-Awesome-in-free-jqGrid-4.8) for example) you will have performance advantages, and the look of *modern web browsers* will looks much better. You should understand the jqGrid 3.8.1 was tested with old (and slow jQuery 1.4.2). The version used with Internet Explorer 8 as the latest IE version (IE9 was published later in March 2011) and it's more oriented on IE6/IE7. The look in modern Chrome/Firefox/Safari can be bad. Is it what you want?

Comment: I'm using version 3.8.1 and there is no option to upgrade to a later version at this point in time.

Comment: @user1334007: See **UPDATED** part of my answer. If it will not help you then you should include **more details** about `colModel`, jqGrid options and how you start inline editing.

Comment: Oleg, thank you for the support, it's much appreciated. The approach I was taking was that I would pull the data for all the lists into a big JSON structure one time when the grid loads, then inside beforeSelectRow/onSelectRow I would quickly look through that structure to find the values I needed for each listbox. So yes getSelectValuesFromJSON() is a synchronous method but that's okay because it doesn't make any AJAX calls.

Comment: great comment about setting key:true on the primary key column for the grid. I wish I had known about that a long time ago! A lot of the code already works like it does in my example but it would definitely be cleaner and simpler if it had been written properly to begin with. I would like to use a more recent version of jqGrid but we simply haven't had time/budget to fully test it out. The UI relies heavily on jqGrid and we don't want to introduce a bunch of regressions by changing the version, especially if we aren't really using it properly to begin with.

Comment: @user1334007: You are welcome! In the way you will get make information from the server which you probably will never use, but if you have not so much rows that the solution can work. By the way you can include **all the information inside of `userdata` part of the server response**. More recent version of jqGrid have `beforeProcessing` callback and one can follow the idea from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17410568/315935) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19427444/315935).

Comment: @user1334007: Because you don't need to set **one value of selects common for all rows** you don't need to use `beforeProcessing`. You can just use `$(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "userData")` (case is important!) to access the `userdata` part of the server response. In the way you can implements `getSelectValuesFromJSON` part without any additional Ajax request.

Comment: another good tip on the userdata parameter. Didn't know that existed, but it makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: @user1334007: You are welcome! In the way you can include the lists of selects based on the page of data. No additional Ajax are required. I understand the problem with support of old working solutions. Never touch a running system. Isn't so. You can still consider to use new version in new projects or if you get some important real problems in the old project.