# ID values for jqGrid select lists

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jQrid version 3.8.1 and I have a grid that displays information about cars. The jQgrid should is set up to display one car per row and one of the columns is a multi-select list that displays which types of seats the car is configured with. A car can have multiple seat types.

[image]

When the user edits a car row, it makes an ajax query to get all of the seats types available in the system and sticks them in the multi-select list. In addition to populating the list, it needs to also select the options already chosen for that car.

[image]

The values inside the Installed Seats column are not simple strings. They have both an ID and a string value. So the ID for "Wire mesh" might be 2883 and the value for "Composite" might be 29991. They are just unique numeric values (basically the primary key from the table they are stored in).

After the multi-select list is populated with all the appropriate Seat values, I need to select the ones that the car currently has installed (in the picture above it's "Steel" and "Wire frame"). I need to do this based on the seat IDs stored for that car. However, I don't know where these value are going to come from. The grid only stores the names for the seats, not the IDs. Hopefully there is a way to make it store both.

The column model looks like this:

```
colModel: [
    { name: 'Year', index: 'Year', editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { multiple: true } },
    { name: 'Make', index: 'Make', editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { multiple: true } },
    { name: 'Body', index: 'Body', editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { multiple: true } },
    { name: 'Seats', index: 'Seats', editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { multiple: true }, cellattr='is-seat-list="1"' }
]
```

Notice that the 'Seats' model has a cell attribute called `is-seat-list`. I'm using this to find the select box in the row inside the 'editRow' function.

The `onSelectRow` handler looks like this:

```
onSelectRow: function (index) {
    var curValues = $('#cargrid').getRowData(index);

    jQuery('#cargrid').jqGrid('editRow', index, true, function(rowId) {

        //when the user edits the row, query for all the seat types and fill in the list
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/getalltheseats',
            complete: function (allSeats, stat) {
                var list = $('#cargrid').find('tr[id="' + rowId + '"] td[is-seat-list="1"] select');
                var $list = $(list);

                //add the all seat types to the list, checking the ones that this car currently has selected
                _.each(allSeats, function(seat) {
                    var selected = '';
                    if(curValues['Seats'].indexOf(seat.ID) !== -1) //<-- what do I do here??
                        selected = 'selected';

                    $list.append($('<option ' + selected + '></option>').attr('value', seat.ID).text(seat.Name));
                });
            });
        });
    });
},
```

The important line is

```
if(curValues['Seats'].indexOf(seat.ID) !== -1)
```

I have the value of the row but it only contains the seat name, not the ID. The data returned from the ajax call contains each seat name and ID but the `<option>` elements don't contain the ID value so I don't know which ones to select in the list.

So the question is, what's the best way to make jqGrid store both the seat names and IDs so that when I create the list dynamically, I can check the `<option>`s  for the seats that have been chosen for that car.

**Note:**
For various reasons the standard `dataUrl` and `buildSelect` features of jqGrid are [not going to work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29855762/how-to-make-jqgrid-dynamically-populate-options-list-based-on-row-data), which is why I'm building the list on the fly in this manner.

Comment: You didn't wrote **which version of jqGrid you use**. Could we stay by the example with two autos and you prepare the full JSFiddle demo with the filled grid? The way with `dataUrl` and `buildSelect` would be preferred and it should work. It do exactly what you need: load the data and select the items from the editing row. If it not work then you should include the code and one will fix it. Additionally you can include at example of JSON response for `Seats` column from `dataUrl`. Something like `{{"ID": 123, "Name": "Steel"}, ...}`. It can be that you will be need to use `formatter: "select"`

Comment: One see on the picture that you use multiselect plugin, but you didn't included the corresponding JavaScript code which show how and where in your code you initialize multiselect on the `<select>` element. You should synchronize the initialization of multiselect with response from `dataUrl`. `buildSelect` will be called for example **after** the data are loaded from the server. So short time later one can initialize multiselect.

Comment: Argh! Forgot to include the jqGrid version again! I added it.

Comment: @Oleg, thanks for the input. I' not using dataUrl and buildSelect because they make a separate call for each cell and I don't want to make that many server calls. Also I think the version of jqGrid may not support adding query string parameters to the dataUrl value. Anyway, I probably will not rewrite it to use dataUrl/buildSelect at this point. You can see a previous post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29855762/how-to-make-jqgrid-dynamically-populate-options-list-based-on-row-data) that talks about why. I will put a jsfiddle together for you, but it's going to take a little while.

Comment: One can probably support the solution which use 3.8.1 and try to develop for IE5 or for Window 4.0, but the investments are too high. You need to write absolute another code as you need in modern version of jqGrid. About  `dataUrl`: all depend on how many different properties exist for `Seats` column. You can load the data **before** you create the grid and then use `editoptions.value` and `formatter: "select"`. It should solve your problem.

Comment: I understand your point, but there simply isn't time or budget to go through an upgrade of jqGrid right now. The entire web app is heavily based on it and upgrading would be a very disruptive endeavor at this point. If the answer is that jQgrid 3.8.1 simply won't support doing what I want to do, I guess that's how it will have to be.

Comment: The version 3.8.1 and many later versions (later as 4.6) are of cause out of support since long time, but I think that can still help you it you answer on the following questions: **How many different properties exist for Seats column?** Can one load **all the values** via Ajax **before** jqGrid will be created? You can create the grid inside of `success` callback of the ajax request. You can construct `value` parameter (in `editoptions`) for 'Seats' column and then create the grid. You should fill the grid data using **ID** values and use `formatter: "select"` additionally.

Comment: @Oleg, I see what you're saying. Basically I would keep a cache of all the Seat values in the browser. There aren't too terribly man so that should probably be okay. But this is a single page web app and there are things the user can to do create more seat values in the application. So I would need a way to refresh the grid so it can pick up the new Seat values inside editoptions.values. Will calling grid.trigger("reloadGrid") achieve that? Or can you only set the editoptions.values the first time the grid is actually created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need additionally add `formatter: "select"` and to populate **ID** values in `Seats` column during filling of the grid. The `formatter: "select"` will decode the IDs and the corresponding Name value will be displayed to the user.

If you would use more recent version of jqGrid the you can use `beforeProcessing` callback created for the purpose. It allows to include all different ID/Name pairs *in the server response for filling of the grid*. It allows you to fill the information needed for the `formatter: "select"` directly in the main server response. You don't need to load the information *before* creating the grid.

If you use retro version of jqGrid (3.8.1) then I hope that you can still use the following trick. You can define `userdata` part of the server response defined **as function**. The outer elements of the server response `root`, `page`, `total`, `records` and `userdata` will be processed **before** the processing the main part with all items. It allows you to modify `editoptions.value` before it will be processed by `formatter: "select"`.

For example the response from the server can looks like

```json
{
    "page": 1,
    "total": 20,
    "records": 400,
    "userdata": {
        "seats": "29991:Composite;42713:Nappa leather;6421:Steel;2883:Wire mesh"
    },
    "rows": [
        {
            "year": 2007,
            "model": "Toyota/Camry",
            "body": "Sedan",
            "seats": "29991,6421"
        },
        {
            "year": 2057,
            "model": "BMW/Series 4",
            "body": "Sedan",
            "seats": "6421,2883"
        }
    ]
}
```

Inside of `jsonReader` you can define `userdata` which set `userdata.seats` as `value` of `editoptions`. You can use `setColProp` method for example to do this.

In the way you will be able to implement all your requirements.

Comment: Oleg, you did it again. Are you the king of customer support or what Thank you so much. I'm having trouble getting it to work with the jQuery multiselect, but I can create another post about that issue.