# jqGrid combobox: how to add values Dynamically

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets, jqgrid

I am developing a web application using JSP & Servlet (IDE: Eclipse, Database: Oracle10).
I am using jqGrid to display records in tabular format.

I want to get values for combobox in `jqGrid` from servlet, so far I have done following.

I am accessing the array passed by Servlet in JSP scriplet.

```
<%
    String[] stageIDs = (String[])request.getAttribute("combo");
%>
```

Following is my colModel:

```
jQuery("#list10_d").jqGrid({
            height: "100%",
            url:'ProtocolJGridServChild?q=2&action=protAction',
            datatype: "xml",
colNames:['Sr. No.','PID',  'SID'],
colModel:[{name:'srNo',index:'srNo', width:35,sortable:true},
{name:'PID',index:'PID', width:100,sortable:false,editable:true,hidden:true},
{name:'SID',index:'SID', width:100, sortable:false, editable:true, edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:<%for(int i=0;i<stageIDs.length;i++)%><%="ID:"+ stageIDs[i]+";"%>}}
],
            rowNum:2,
            rowList:[2,4,6],
            pager: '#pager10_d',
            sortname: 'PID',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "asc",
            multiselect: true,
            editurl: "MyServletName",
            caption:"CRM_PROT_ACTIONS",
}).navGrid('#pager10_d',{edit:true,add:true,del:true});
```

But I am getting an exception in `for loop line` where I am assigning the editoptions to the combobox. Please let me know is there any mistake in code.

My another question is that is there any better way of assigning values to combobox in jqGrid from servlet (without using scriplet)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `dataUrl` instead of `value` inside of [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions) to get values for combobox from the server. If the server return JSON data instead of HTML fragment you can use `buildSelect` to convert server response from `dataUrl` to the format which jqGrid need. The exact implementation could depend on the version of jqGrid which you use. You can use `ajaxSelectOptions` to change `type` or `dataType` of the corresponding Ajax request from default "html" to `"json"` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7098621/315935)). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7877286/315935) an example of `buildSelect` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

To add combobox to jqgrid wih dynamic data..

I have done it using following way.

```
jQuery("#list10_d").jqGrid({
        height: "100%",
        url:'ProtocolJGridServChild?q=2&action=protAction',
        datatype: "xml",
colNames:['Sr. No.','PID',  'SID'],
colModel:[{name:'srNo',index:'srNo', width:35,sortable:true},
{name:'PID',index:'PID', width:100,sortable:false,editable:true,hidden:true},
{name:'SID',index:'SID', width:100,sortable:false,editable:true,edittype:"select",editoptions: {dataUrl: 'MyServletURL?action=comboSID'}},
],
        rowNum:2,
        rowList:[2,4,6],
        pager: '#pager10_d',
        sortname: 'PID',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "asc",
        multiselect: true,
        editurl: "MyServletName",
        caption:"CRM_PROT_ACTIONS",
}).navGrid('#pager10_d',{edit:true,add:true,del:true});
```

**Servlet**

```
if(request.getParameter("action").equalsIgnoreCase("comboSID"))
{
        String s[][] = select.getData("select SID from TABLE_NAME_HERE where PID='"+ param +"'"); //returns 2D array
        StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer();
        strBuf.append("<select>");
        for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
        {
            strBuf.append("<option>");
            strBuf.append(s[i][0]);
            strBuf.append("</option>");
        }
        strBuf.append("</select>");
        out.println(strBuf);
}
```