# How to Fix position of headers in subgrid of JQGrid?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, header, scroll

I've a sub-grid and height of sub-grid is set to auto.

```
height:"auto"
```

Here, I need to fix the position of headers, When i scroll down. But there is no scroll bar for sub-grid. Because i don't want multiple scroll bars in side my grid. Only one scroll bar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't clear understand your problem. Which "headers" you mean: the column headers of subgrid or the caption of the subgrids? What problem exist if you scroll down the grid having subgrids? What is wrong with the subgrid headers? What exactly behavior you wait for?

Comment: I mean the captions of Sub grid. That is name of the columns. If i scroll down the subgrid. Column headers of subgrid goes up. I want these column headers of subgrid to be fixed. As i scroll subgrid down headers will remain below parent grid headers as fixed position.

Answer (score 1):

If the column headers of the subgrid will be fixed during scrolling of the main grid the headers will be overlapped with the contain of the next row of the main grid. In any way it is not possible what you want.

One tip as a workaround which I can suggest you: you can overwrite default tooltips shown if the mouse cursor is over the cells of subgrid. The default tooltips are the same as the cell contain. You can change behavior using `cellattr` (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862317/jqgrid-boolean-or-enumeration-dropdown-filtering-for-columns/6863704#6863704) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405248/can-jqgrid-hover-text-be-defined-with-addrowdata/7408355#7408355) as an example). The `colModel` element in the subgrid having

```
cellattr: function () { return ' title="My column name"'; }
```

will display the text "My column name" as the tooltip. I personally use the way for all columns having `formatter: 'checkbox'`. If you have many such columns and you want to examine some column in the middle of grid then it helps to determine to which column the cell belongs. In your case you have the same problem. So you can use the same `cellattr` property of the column.