# jqgrid: Multi-line headings

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid table with must contain some lengthy strings in the header cells.
What is the proper way to format them?

Just using the standard long string does not work since it will be cut at the right
border of the cell if the cell width is too small.

Using a BR tag inside the text also does not work since the text after the BR tag is not being displayed (even after changing the height of the cell header through CSS).

Any proper way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [headertitles: true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) option to display tooltips with the full header text.

Moreover depend on your requirements you can consider to use **wrapping** of the column headers described in details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7256972/315935). One more alternative is to **rotate** column headers. I personally frequently use the way in case of having column with short contain the cells (like checkboxs) and long text in the column headers (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3979490/315935)).