# change the look of search box

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jquery and jqgrid plugin , i have enable the search functionality in a jqgrid 
and rite now i can see following search box as follows

[image: FIG 1]

and i want to make it look like as follows with some custom textbox and checkboxes. 
i want to make `begins with` by default for a name field.

But i don't know how can i change the look and put some customized field into search box ?

[image]

Comment: You can create the form yourself and trigger the filtering manually. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3979490/315935) which describes the idea of the implementation. If you want to use "Find" button to trigger the searching your code could be much more simple.

Comment: or you can modify/override the css of the original form. This will let you change the look and feel