# How to get form data with column filter in jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

How to get form data while column filter in jqgrid

I have used external check box also using the updated answer code from [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974324/jqgrid-using-multiple-methods-to-filter-data/3979490#3979490)

I have used the working example reference [Link](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CheckboxesWithVerticalHeaders1.htm)

```
jQuery("#list451").jqGrid({ 
url:'getList.php?mode=result_list', 
datatype: "json",
height: 255, 
width: 600, 
colNames:['Index','Name', 'Code','Result'], 
colModel:[
{name:'item_id',index:'item_id', width:65, sorttype:'integer',searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','le','lt','gt','ge']}},
{name:'item',index:'item', width:150, sorttype:'string',searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','bw','bn','cn','nc','ew','en']}},
{name:'item_cd',index:'item_cd', width:100} ,
{name:'result',index:'result', width:100,sorttype:'string',searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne']} ], 
rowNum:50, 
rowTotal: 200,
rowList : [20,30,50], 
loadonce:false, 
mtype: "GET", 
rownumbers: true,
rownumWidth: 40, 
gridview: true, 
pager: '#pager451', 
sortname:'item_id', 
viewrecords: true, 
sortorder: "asc", 
caption: "Loading data from server at once" });
jQuery("#list451").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{searchOperators : true});
```

External check box code Actions in script

```
 //Pass fail code check box
            $("#pass").change(function() {
                var f = {groupOp:"AND",rules:[]};
                if($("#pass").is(':checked')) {
                   f.rules.push({field:"result",op:"eq",data:"pass"});
                }

                grid[0].p.search = f.rules.length>0;
                $.extend(grid[0].p.postData,{filters:JSON.stringify(f)});
                grid.trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:1}]);
            });
```

Check box html Code is below

```
<input type="checkbox" name="pass" id="pass">Pass
```

In above pass/fail code working for check box click to sort the pass/fail in grid.

I want if pass check box checked then i will enter item name in search box and choose the not equal search operation after enter to am not getting the pass check box value in server side. I got a search box value and search operators but i am not get the pass check box value.

**I want pass check box value in server side.Please help me**

Comment: I am not using external search bar, i am using grid column filter only.

Comment: Working example demo reference is http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CheckboxesWithVerticalHeaders1.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that I correctly understand your problem. If you use *remote* `datatype` (like `datatype: "json"` in your code) and without usage of `loadonce: true` option then *the server* is responsible to return filtered data. The server get `filters` parameter. It's JSON formatted string in the format described in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#options). If you implement decoding of `filters` in the format you can use *any* searching/filter functionality of jqGrid (advanced searching, filter toolbar etc).

If you have problem to implement filtering based on the standard `filters` parameter you can just send the information about the filters in free format which you can define yourself. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935) for more details. In case of [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CheckboxesWithVerticalHeaders1.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3979490/315935) one have checkboxes with ids `cb_pending`, `cb_processing` and `cb_delivered`. If you would add `postData` parameter in for example the following form

```js
postData: {
    pending: function () { return $("#cb_pending").is(':checked'); },
    processing: function () { return $("#cb_processing").is(':checked'); },
    delivered: function () { return $("#cb_delivered").is(':checked'); }
}
```

then `pending`, `processing` and `delivered` parameters will be added to the server every time.

Alternatively you can use [jQuery.serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) or [jQuery.serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/) to get all values of one HTML form at once instead of queering every checkbox separately by id.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oleg..........Its working fine......i had solved more number of issues with your help....